# Django/Python - Grouping objects by common set from a many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django, algorithm, puzzle

This is a part algorithm-logic question (how to do it), part implementation question (how to do it best!). I'm working with Django, so I thought I'd share with that.

In Python, it's worth mentioning that the problem is somewhat related to [how-do-i-use-pythons-itertoolsgroupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertoolsgroupby).

Suppose you're given two Django Model-derived classes:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    mods = models.ManyToManyField(Representative)
```

and

```
from django.db import models

class Mods(models.Model):
   ...
```

How does one get a list of Cars, grouped by Cars with a common set of Mods?

I.e. I want to get a class likeso:

```
Cars_by_common_mods = [ 
  { mods: { 'a' }, cars: { 'W1', 'W2' } },
  { mods: { 'a', 'b' }, cars: { 'X1', 'X2', 'X3' }, },
  { mods: { 'b' }, cars: { 'Y1', 'Y2' } },
  { mods: { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, cars: { 'Z1' } },
]
```

I've been thinking of something like:

```
def cars_by_common_mods():
  cars = Cars.objects.all()

  mod_list = []      

  for car in cars:
    mod_list.append( { 'car': car, 'mods': list(car.mods.all()) } 

  ret = []

  for key, mods_group in groupby(list(mods), lambda x: set(x.mods)):
    ret.append(mods_group)

  return ret
```

However, that doesn't work because (perhaps among other reasons) the groupby doesn't seem to group by the mods sets. I guess the mod_list has to be sorted to work with groupby. All to say, I'm confident there's something simple and elegant out there that will be both enlightening and illuminating.

*Cheers & thanks!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried sorting the list first? The algorithm you proposed should work, albeit with lots of database hits.

```
import itertools

cars = [
    {'car': 'X2', 'mods': [1,2]},
    {'car': 'Y2', 'mods': [2]},
    {'car': 'W2', 'mods': [1]},
    {'car': 'X1', 'mods': [1,2]},
    {'car': 'W1', 'mods': [1]},
    {'car': 'Y1', 'mods': [2]},
    {'car': 'Z1', 'mods': [1,2,3]},
    {'car': 'X3', 'mods': [1,2]},
]

cars.sort(key=lambda car: car['mods'])

cars_by_common_mods = {}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(cars, lambda car: car['mods']):
    cars_by_common_mods[frozenset(k)] = [car['car'] for car in g]

print cars_by_common_mods
```

Now, about those queries:

```
import collections
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT car_id, mod_id FROM someapp_car_mod ORDER BY 1, 2')
cars = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    cars[row[0]].append(row[1])

# Here's one I prepared earlier, which emulates the sample data we've been working
# with so far, but using the car id instead of the previous string.
cars = {
    1: [1,2],
    2: [2],
    3: [1],
    4: [1,2],
    5: [1],
    6: [2],
    7: [1,2,3],
    8: [1,2],
}

sorted_cars = sorted(cars.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
cars_by_common_mods = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_cars, key=itemgetter(1)):
    cars_by_common_mods.append({'mods': k, 'cars': map(itemgetter(0), g)})

print cars_by_common_mods

# Which, for the sample data gives me (reformatted by hand for clarity)
[{'cars': [3, 5],    'mods': [1]},
 {'cars': [1, 4, 8], 'mods': [1, 2]},
 {'cars': [7],       'mods': [1, 2, 3]},
 {'cars': [2, 6],    'mods': [2]}]
```

Now that you've got your lists of car ids and mod ids, if you need the complete objects to work with, you could do a single query for each to get a complete list for each model and create a lookup `dict` for those, keyed by their ids  - then, I believe, Bob is your proverbial father's brother.

Answer (score 2):

check [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). it's only for templates, but i guess this kind of classification belongs to the presentation layer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at regroup, but the (unstated) problem is that there is more logic to be done after the initial groupings. It's a good tip, though; will see if I can design it around regroup.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here.

You didn't sort your list before calling groupby, and this is required. From [itertools documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5/lib/itertools-functions.html):

> Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

Then, you don't duplicate the list returned by groupby. Again, documentation states:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with
>   groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the groupby object is advanced, the
>   previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should 
>   be stored as a list:
>
> ```
> groups = []
> uniquekeys = []
> for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
>     groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
>     uniquekeys.append(k)
> ```

And final mistake is using sets as keys. They don't work here. A quick fix is to cast them to sorted tuples (there could be a better solution, but I cannot think of it now).

So, in your example, the last part should look like this:

```
sortMethod = lambda x: tuple(sorted(set(x.mods)))
sortedMods = sorted(list(mods), key=sortMethod)
for key, mods_group in groupby(sortedMods, sortMethod):
    ret.append(list(mods_group))
```

Comment: I return to this answer all the time. haha

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a concern (i.e. lots of cars on a page, or a high-traffic site), [denormalization](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/9a672d5bbbe67562) makes sense, and simplifies your problem as a side effect.

Be aware that denormalizing many-to-many relations might be a bit tricky though. I haven't run into any such code examples yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the helpful replies. I've been plugging away at this problem. A 'best' solution still eludes me, but I've some thoughts.

I should mention that the statistics of the data-set I'm working with. In 75% of the cases there will be one Mod. In 24% of the cases, two. In 1% of the cases there will be zero, or three or more. For every Mod, there is at least one unique Car, though a Mod may be applied to numerous Cars.

Having said that, I've considered (but not implemented) something like-so:

```
class ModSet(models.Model):
  mods = models.ManyToManyField(Mod)
```

and change cars to

```
class Car(models.Model):
  modset = models.ForeignKey(ModSet)
```

It's trivial to group by Car.modset: I can use regroup, as suggested by Javier, for example. It seems a simpler and reasonably elegant solution; thoughts would be much appreciated.