# Identify groups of consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, grouping

I'd like to identify groups of consecutive numbers in a list, so that:

```
myfunc([2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20])
```

Returns:

```
[(2,5), (12,17), 20]
```

And was wondering what the best way to do this was (particularly if there's something inbuilt into Python).

Edit: Note I originally forgot to mention that individual numbers should be returned as individual numbers, not ranges.

Comment: Is that return value a string?

Comment: Ideally would prefer something that uses a separate type for ranges vs standalone numbers.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) was added in version 4.0.

**Demo**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]
[list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)]
# [[2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [20]]
```

**Code**

Applying this tool, we make a generator function that finds ranges of consecutive numbers.

```
def find_ranges(iterable):
    """Yield range of consecutive numbers."""
    for group in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable):
        group = list(group)
        if len(group) == 1:
            yield group[0]
        else:
            yield group[0], group[-1]


iterable = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]
list(find_ranges(iterable))
# [(2, 5), (12, 17), 20]
```

The [source](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L1623-L1657) implementation emulates a [classic recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples) (as demonstrated by @Nadia Alramli).

*Note: `more_itertools` is a third-party package installable via [`pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).*

Comment: Alternatively, using `more_itertools.groupby_transform`: `[v for k,v in more_itertools.groupby_transform(enumerate(iterable), keyfunc=lambda p: p[1]-p[0], valuefunc=operator.itemgetter(1), reducefunc=to_interval)]` with `to_interval = lambda g: (sublst[0], sublst[-1]) if len(sublst := list(g)) > 1 else sublst[0]`

Answer (score 146):

**EDIT 2: To answer the OP new requirement**

```
ranges = []
for key, group in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (index, item): index - item):
    group = map(itemgetter(1), group)
    if len(group) > 1:
        ranges.append(xrange(group[0], group[-1]))
    else:
        ranges.append(group[0])
```

Output:

```
[xrange(2, 5), xrange(12, 17), 20]
```

You can replace xrange with range or any other custom class.

---

Python docs have a very neat [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples) for this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    print(map(itemgetter(1), g))
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

If you want to get the exact same output, you can do this:

```
ranges = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
    ranges.append((group[0], group[-1]))
```

output:

```
[(2, 5), (12, 17)]
```

---

**EDIT:** The example is already explained in the documentation but maybe I should explain it more:

> The key to the solution is
> differencing with a range so that
> consecutive numbers all appear in same
> group.

If the data was: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]`
Then `groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x)` is equivalent of the following:

```
groupby(
    [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 12),
    (5, 13), (6, 14), (7, 15), (8, 16), (9, 17)],
    lambda (i,x):i-x
)
```

The lambda function subtracts the element index from the element value. So when you apply the lambda on each item. You'll get the following keys for groupby:

```
[-2, -2, -2, -2, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8]
```

groupby groups elements by equal key value, so the first 4 elements will be grouped together and so forth.

I hope this makes it more readable.

`python 3` version may be helpful for beginners

import the libraries required first

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

ranges =[]

for k,g in groupby(enumerate(data),lambda x:x[0]-x[1]):
    group = (map(itemgetter(1),g))
    group = list(map(int,group))
    ranges.append((group[0],group[-1]))
```

Comment: almost works in py3k, except it requires `lambda x:x[0]-x[1]`.

Comment: Could you use please use multi-character variable names? For someone not familiar with map() or groupby(), the meanings of k g, i and x are not clear.

Comment: This was copied from the Python documentations with the same variable names. I changed the names now.

Comment: Thanks for the improved variable names and handling non-ranged numbers. This is readable, your explanations are great and I've marked this as the preferred answer.

Comment: You'll need to increment the 2nd number in xrange/range because it is non-inclusive. In other words, `[2,3,4,5] == xrange(2,6)`, not `xrange(2,5)`. It may be worth defining a new inclusive range data type.

Comment: Python 3 throws a syntax error on the first example. Here's the first 2 lines updated to work on python 3:
`for key, group in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda i: i[0] - i[1]):
        group = list(map(itemgetter(1), group))`

Answer (score 25):

The "naive" solution which I find somewhat readable atleast.

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 25, 26, 28, 51, 52, 57]

def group(L):
    first = last = L[0]
    for n in L[1:]:
        if n - 1 == last: # Part of the group, bump the end
            last = n
        else: # Not part of the group, yield current group and start a new
            yield first, last
            first = last = n
    yield first, last # Yield the last group


>>>print list(group(x))
[(2, 5), (12, 17), (22, 22), (25, 26), (28, 28), (51, 52), (57, 57)]
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot because it's terse yet readable. 

However numbers that are outside of ranges should be printed as single digits, not tuples (as I will format the output and have different formatting requirements for individual numbers versus ranges of numbers.

Comment: The other answer looked beautiful and intelligent, but this one is more understandable to me and allowed a beginner like me to expand it according to my needs.

Comment: Could use a list comprehension to print the non-range tuples as single digits: 
`print([i if i[0] != i[1] else i[0] for i in group(x)])`

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your list is sorted:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def ranges(lst):
    pos = (j - i for i, j in enumerate(lst))
    t = 0
    for i, els in groupby(pos):
        l = len(list(els))
        el = lst[t]
        t += l
        yield range(el, el+l)


>>> lst = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
>>> list(ranges(lst))
[range(2, 6), range(12, 18)]
```

Comment: `[j - i for i, j in enumerate(lst)]` is clever :-)

Answer (score 11):

Here it is something that should work, without any import needed:

```
def myfunc(lst):
    ret = []
    a = b = lst[0]                           # a and b are range's bounds

    for el in lst[1:]:
        if el == b+1: 
            b = el                           # range grows
        else:                                # range ended
            ret.append(a if a==b else (a,b)) # is a single or a range?
            a = b = el                       # let's start again with a single
    ret.append(a if a==b else (a,b))         # corner case for last single/range
    return ret
```

Answer (score 8):

Please note that the code using `groupby` doesn't work as given in Python 3 so use this.

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x:x[0]-x[1]):
    group = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    ranges.append((group[0], group[-1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my method in which I tried to prioritize readability. Note that it returns a tuple of the same values if there is only one value in a group. That can be fixed easily in the second snippet I'll post.

```
def group(values):
    """return the first and last value of each continuous set in a list of sorted values"""

    values = sorted(values)
    first = last = values[0]

    for index in values[1:]:
        if index - last > 1:  # triggered if in a new group
            yield first, last

            first = index  # update first only if in a new group

        last = index  # update last on every iteration

    yield first, last  # this is needed to yield the last set of numbers
```

Here is the result of a test:

```
values = [0, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 30, 44, 45, 50]
result = list(group(values))
print(result)
```

result = `[(0, 0), (5, 7), (12, 13), (21, 26), (30, 30), (44, 45), (50, 50)]`

If you want to return only a single value in the case of a single value in a group, just add a conditional check to the yields:

```
def group(values):
    """return the first and last value of each continuous set in a list of sorted values"""

    values = sorted(values)

    first = last = values[0]

    for index in values[1:]:
        if index - last > 1:  # triggered if in a new group
            if first == last:
                yield first

            else:
                yield first, last

            first = index  # update first only if in a new group

        last = index  # update last on every iteration

    if first == last:
        yield first

    else:
        yield first, last
```

result = `[0, (5, 7), (12, 13), (21, 26), 30, (44, 45), 50]`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't use a standard function - it just iiterates over the input, but it should work:

```
def myfunc(l):
    r = []
    p = q = None
    for x in l + [-1]:
        if x - 1 == q:
            q += 1
        else:
            if p:
               if q > p:
                   r.append('%s-%s' % (p, q))
               else:
                   r.append(str(p))
            p = q = x
    return '(%s)' % ', '.join(r)
```

Note that it requires that the input contains only positive numbers in ascending order. You should validate the input, but this code is omitted for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

myarray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]
sequences = np.split(myarray, np.array(np.where(np.diff(myarray) > 1)[0]) + 1)
l = []
for s in sequences:
    if len(s) > 1:
        l.append((np.min(s), np.max(s)))
    else:
        l.append(s[0])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(2, 5), (12, 17), 20]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this way is simpler than any of the answers I've seen here (Edit: fixed based on comment from Pleastry):

```
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]

starts = [x for x in data if x-1 not in data and x+1 in data]
ends = [x for x in data if x-1 in data and x+1 not in data and x not in starts]
singles = [x for x in data if x-1 not in data and x+1 not in data]
list(zip(starts, ends)) + singles
```

Output:

```
[(2, 5), (12, 17), 20]
```

---

Edited:

As @dawg notes, this is O(n**2). One option to improve performance would be to convert the original list to a set (and also the starts list to a set) i.e.

```
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]
data_as_set = set(data)

starts = [x for x in data_as_set if x-1 not in data_as_set and x+1 in data_as_set]
startset = set(starts)
ends = [x for x in data_as_set if x-1 in data_as_set and x+1 not in data_as_set and x not in startset]
singles = [x for x in data_as_set if x-1 not in data_as_set and x+1 not in data_as_set]

print(list(zip(starts, ends)) + singles)
```

Comment: This actually fails if you replace 12 with 10 in data array. The correct solution would be: `starts = [x for x in data if x-1 not in data and x+1 in data]` and `ends = [x for x in data if x-1 in data and x+1 not in data and x not in starts]`

Comment: Thanks @Pleastry - I have edited with your fix

Comment: This is one of the most elegant solutions that I came across.

Comment: This has `On**2` complexity.

Comment: @dawg Well, yes, though wasn't something OP mentioned. I have edited a suggested improvement. Was there a reason you only picked my answer to comment on complexity?

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` and `count` from `itertools` gives us a short solution. The idea is that, in an increasing sequence, the difference between the index and the value will remain the same.

In order to keep track of the index, we can use an [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), which makes the code cleaner as using `enumerate`:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def intervals(data):
    out = []
    counter = count()

    for key, group in groupby(data, key = lambda x: x-next(counter)):
        block = list(group)
        out.append([block[0], block[-1]])
    return out
```

Some sample output:

```
print(intervals([0, 1, 3, 4, 6]))
# [[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]

print(intervals([2, 3, 4, 5]))
# [[2, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer I came up with. I'm writing the code for other people to understand, so I'm fairly verbose with variable names and comments.

First a quick helper function:

```
def getpreviousitem(mylist,myitem):
    '''Given a list and an item, return previous item in list'''
    for position, item in enumerate(mylist):
        if item == myitem:
            # First item has no previous item
            if position == 0:
                return None
            # Return previous item    
            return mylist[position-1]
```

And then the actual code:

```
def getranges(cpulist):
    '''Given a sorted list of numbers, return a list of ranges'''
    rangelist = []
    inrange = False
    for item in cpulist:
        previousitem = getpreviousitem(cpulist,item)
        if previousitem == item - 1:
            # We're in a range
            if inrange == True:
                # It's an existing range - change the end to the current item
                newrange[1] = item
            else:    
                # We've found a new range.
                newrange = [item-1,item]
            # Update to show we are now in a range    
            inrange = True    
        else:   
            # We were in a range but now it just ended
            if inrange == True:
                # Save the old range
                rangelist.append(newrange)
            # Update to show we're no longer in a range    
            inrange = False 
    # Add the final range found to our list
    if inrange == True:
        rangelist.append(newrange)
    return rangelist
```

Example run:

```
getranges([2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
```

returns:

```
[[2, 5], [12, 17]]
```

Comment: `>>> getranges([2, 12, 13])` Outputs: `[[12, 13]]`. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yep, I need to fix for individual numbers (per most of the answers on the page). Working on it now.

Comment: Actually I prefer Nadia's answer, groupby() seems like the standard function I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy + comprehension lists:
With numpy diff function, consequent input vector entries that their difference is not equal to one can be identified. The start and end of the input vector need to be considered.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20])

d = [i for i, df in enumerate(np.diff(data)) if df!= 1] 
d = np.hstack([-1, d, len(data)-1])  # add first and last elements 
d = np.vstack([d[:-1]+1, d[1:]]).T

print(data[d])
```

Output:

```
 [[ 2  5]   
  [12 17]   
  [20 20]]
```

Note: The request that individual numbers should be treated differently, (returned as individual, not ranges) was omitted. This can be reached by further post-processing the results. Usually this will make things more complex without gaining any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner in Python 2.7 if interested:

```
x = [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21]

d = iter(x[:1] + sum(([i1, i2] for i1, i2 in zip(x, x[1:] + x[:1]) if i2 != i1+1), []))

print zip(d, d)

>>> [(2, 3), (6, 8), (14, 15), (19, 21)]
```

Comment: Might be a few years too late for a Python 2.7 answer.

Comment: Some people are actually stuck at Python 2.7. In my case, the softwares I work with leave me no other choice. This answer was supposed to help people in the same situation.

Comment: Works for me in 3.8 with some minor changes

Comment: just `print(zip(d, d))` for `python 3`

Answer (score 1):

One more prettiness:

```
from itertools import groupby

def myfunc(lst):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0]):
        first = last = next(g)[1]
        for _, last in g: pass
        yield first if first==last else (first, last)

>>> list(myfunc([2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20]))
[(2, 5), (12, 17), 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

A short solution that works without additional imports. It accepts any iterable, sorts unsorted inputs, and removes duplicate items:

```
def ranges(nums):
    nums = sorted(set(nums))
    gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]
    edges = iter(nums[:1] + sum(gaps, []) + nums[-1:])
    return list(zip(edges, edges))
```

Example:

```
>>> ranges([2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 15])
[(2, 4), (7, 9), (15, 15)]

>>> ranges([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 15, 100])
[(-1, 3), (12, 13), (15, 15), (100, 100)]

>>> ranges(range(100))
[(0, 99)]

>>> ranges([0])
[(0, 0)]

>>> ranges([])
[]
```

This is the same as @dansalmo's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20725061/650222) which I found amazing, albeit a bit hard to read and apply (as it's not given as a function).

Note that it could easily be modified to spit out "traditional" open ranges `[start, end)`, by e.g. altering the return statement:

```
    return [(s, e+1) for s, e in zip(edges, edges)]
```

I copied this answer over from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48106843/650222) that was marked as a duplicate of this one with the intention to make it easier findable (after I just now searched again for this topic, finding only the question here at first and not being satisfied with the answers given).

Answer (score 0):

The versions by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154312/1089161), [Andrea Ambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155283/1089161), [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154409/1089161), [Nadia Alramli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154437/1089161), and [truppo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154741/1089161) are simple and fast. The 'truppo' version encouraged me to write a version that retains the same nimble behavior while handling step sizes other than 1 (and lists as singletons elements that don't extend more than 1 step with a given step size). It is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255692/1089161).

```
>>> list(ranges([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,3,5,7,11,1,2,3]))
[(1, 4, 1), (3, 1, -1), (3, 7, 2), 11, (1, 3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach , but here is my 2 cents

```
def getConsecutiveValues2(arr): 
    x = ""
    final = []
    end = 0
    start = 0
    for i in range(1,len(arr)) :
        if arr[i] - arr[i-1] == 1 :
            end = i
        else :
            print(start,end)
            final.append(arr[start:end+1])
            start = i
        if i == len(arr) - 1 :
            final.append(arr[start:end+1])
    return final

x = [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12]
print(getConsecutiveValues2(x))

>> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**This implementation works for regular or irregular steps**

I needed to achieve the same thing but with the slight difference where steps can be irregular. this is my implementation

```
def ranges(l):
    if not len(l):
        return range(0,0)
    elif len(l)==1:
        return range(l[0],l[0]+1)
    # get steps
    sl    = sorted(l)
    steps = [i-j for i,j in zip(sl[1:],sl[:-1])]
    # get unique steps indexes range
    groups = [[0,0,steps[0]],]
    for i,s in enumerate(steps):
        if s==groups[-1][-1]:
            groups[-1][1] = i+1
        else:
            groups.append( [i+1,i+1,s] )
            g2 = groups[-2]
            if g2[0]==g2[1]:
                if sl[i+1]-sl[i]==s:
                    _=groups.pop(-2)
                    groups[-1][0] = i
    # create list of ranges 
    return [range(sl[i],sl[j]+s,s) if s!=0 else [sl[i]]*(j+1-i) for i,j,s in groups]
```

Here's an example

```
from timeit import timeit

# for regular ranges
l = list(range(1000000))
ranges(l)
>>> [range(0, 1000000)]
l = list(range(10)) + list(range(20,25)) + [1,2,3]
ranges(l)
>>> [range(0, 2), range(1, 3), range(2, 4), range(3, 10), range(20, 25)]
sorted(l);[list(i) for i in ranges(l)]
>>> [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
>>> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

# for irregular steps list
l = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 100, 200, 300, 400, 60, 99, 4000,4001]
ranges(l)
>>> [range(1, 9, 2), range(10, 13), range(60, 138, 39), range(100, 500, 100), range(4000, 4002)]

## Speed test
timeit("ranges(l)","from __main__ import ranges,l", number=1000)/1000
>>> 9.303160999934334e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution if you expect your input to be a set:

```py
def group_years(years):
  consecutive_years = []
  for year in years:
    close = {y for y in years if abs(y - year) == 1}
    for group in consecutive_years:
      if len(close.intersection(group)):
        group |= close
        break
    else:
      consecutive_years.append({year, *close})
  
  return consecutive_years
```

Example:

```
group_years({2016, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2022})
Out[54]: [{2016, 2017}, {2019, 2020}, {2022}]
```