# Breaking a list into sublist segments

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 9, 28, 29]
```

I'd like to generate a nested list where the original list is broken into sublist of consecutive numbers:

```
sub_list = [[4], [6, 7, 8, 9], [12], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [28, 29]
```

I'm struggling to figure out how I can do this. Can anyone provide a function to generate this?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list

Comment: Turns out it's like a duplicate :)

Comment: Most excellent! Thanks. Should have known, groupby is frequently the answer for this type of thing.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate because the original list isn't sorted. The accepted answers to the other questions aren't applicable here.