# Comparing Difference between Values within Python List

Tags: python, list, slice

Let's say I have a list of integers:

```
list = [1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12]
```

And I'd like to divide the list in to three separate lists, with the split occurring between consecutive integers with a difference >=2, which would give me

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [5, 6, 7]
list3 = [10, 11, 12]
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Python? I would like to do this in order to analyze data from a psychology experiment, where I have a list of timestamped response and want to cluster responses based on how far apart they are

Comment: Does it have to be three separate lists?

Comment: What would you do if you have such list instead - [1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,25]? It won't make it into 3 lists, but 5 instead

Comment: Is there a homework question? If so please state this. if not please elaborate about what approaches you are thinking about. also giving an example of what you are trying to do would help, this is quite vague

Comment: BTW, don't give your variables names like `list` - it will mask out the intrinsic names and will give you unexpected consequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list). The answers there show you how to divide a list into sublists of consecutive integers.

From the accepted answer there:

```
>>> data = [ 1, 4,5,6, 10, 15,16,17,18, 22, 25,26,27,28]
>>> for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
...     print map(itemgetter(1), g)
...
[1]
[4, 5, 6]
[10]
[15, 16, 17, 18]
[22]
[25, 26, 27, 28]
```

The answer doesn't offer any explanation of what's going on here, so I'll explain. First, it assumes that `data` is sorted in ascending order. Enumerating `data` then gives a list of index, value pairs. It then uses the index minus the value as a key for grouping the items. Take a look at what this does for your list:

```
>>> myList = [1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> [i - x for i, x in enumerate(myList)]
[-1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -4, -4, -4]
```

As you can see, consecutive values end up having the same grouping key. This is because

> if data[i] + 1 == data[i+1]:
>
> then data[i] - i == data[i] + 1 - 1 - i == data[i+1] - (i + 1)

FYI, `groupby` comes from `itertools` and `itemgetter` comes from `operator`. So add these lines to your imports:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
```

Just be aware that this solution will only work if `data` is sorted and does not contain any duplicates. Of course, it's fairly straightforward to turn a list into a sorted set:

```
>>> myList = [1, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 11, 1, 2]
>>> myList = list(sorted(set(myList)))
>>> print myList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Terrific explanation, very helpful!

Comment: In plain words, if you start from whatever index, n, let's say, the difference between that  index and corresponding element would be some number, d. If the next number or numbers are consecutive, the difference will stay constant as both, the index and the element, grow by 1 which cancels out during the subtraction operation.