# How to check subsequence exists in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

In python, it's possible to use the `is` keyword to check for contains, e.g.

```
>>> 3 in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
```

But this doesn't yield the same output if it's checking whether a list of a single integer is inside the reference list `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

```
>>> [3] in [1,2,3,4,5]
False
```

Also, checking a subsequence in the reference list cannot be achieved with:

```
>>> [3,4,5] in [1,2,3,4,5]
False
```

**Is there a way to have a function that checks for subsequence such that the following returns true?** e.g. a function call `x_in_y()`:

```
>>> x_in_y([3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> x_in_y([3], [1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> x_in_y(3, [1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> x_in_y([2,3], [1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> x_in_y([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5])
False
>>> x_in_y([1,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
False
```

**Maybe something from `itertools` or `operator`?**

(Note, the input lists can be non-unique)

Comment: i think this has been answered already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x_in_y()` can be implemented by slicing the original list and comparing the slices to the input list:

```
def x_in_y(query, base):
    try:
        l = len(query)
    except TypeError:
        l = 1
        query = type(base)((query,))

    for i in range(len(base)):
        if base[i:i+l] == query:
            return True
    return False
```

Change `range` to `xrange` if you are using Python2.

Comment: You can change `range(len(base))` to `range(len(base) - l + 1)` to avoid some superfluous processing.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe something like this:

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    return all([s in my_list for s in search_list])
```

provided the `search_list` is a list.

Comment: This only checks that all items in `search_list` exist individually in `my_list` - it doesn't check that they exist as a subsequence, so the `x_in_y([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5])` test incorrectly returns True.

Comment: Also: `x_in_y([1, 1, 1, 1], [1])`