# python grouper object could not print anything after using itemgetter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, iteritems

I was running the example at

[Detecting consecutive integers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter    

data = [ 1, 4,5,6, 10, 15,16,17,18, 22, 25,26,27,28]

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda ix: ix[0] - ix[1]):
    result = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    print (result)

    for t in g:
        print(t)
```

but the 2nd print in the loop could not print anything out.

why is that

Comment: Because you exhausted the iterator.

Comment: Capture the content of the iterator `g`.  Example: add this after the first `for` loop.  `g = list(g)`