# Fetching values with consecutive keys from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary like:

```
{0:'I', 3: 'Mr.', 5: 'Nevrekar', 8: 'JK', 14: 'Soham', 15: 'Sharma',  4: 'Akshay'}
```

I want to return it the 1st combination of consecutive keys(minimum 2).
In above case it's (3,4,5).

so it would return a list:

```
['Mr.', 'Akshay', 'Nevrekar'].
```

How can I achieve this?

My Attempt:

```
name=[]
count = 0
for k,g in name_list.items():
    if count == 0:
        temp =None
    if k-1 == temp:
        name.append(g)

    count+= 1
    temp = k
```

which is giving output as:

```
['Akshay', 'Nevrekar', 'Sharma']
```

Comment: why not (14, 15) as well?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't guarranteed to be ordered. In python 3.7 - "the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec."

Comment: I just want the 1st combination of consecutive keys. It should ignore the rest.

Comment: After ['Mr.', 'Akshay', 'Nevrekar'] what is next in sequence?

Comment: @PraysonDaniel  For above input that;s it. It should not return anything after that(Ideally break the loop).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list

Comment: Use collection ;) see code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *recipe* from `more_itertools` that comes in handy here:

```
import more_itertools as mit

d = {0:'I', 3: 'Mr.', 4: 'Akshay', 5: 'Nevrekar', 8: 'JK', 14: 'Soham', 15: 'Sharma'}
cons = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(sorted(d.keys()))]
# [[0], [3, 4, 5], [8], [14, 15]]
res = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in cons if len(x)>1]
# [['Mr.', 'Akshay', 'Nevrekar'], ['Soham', 'Sharma']]
```

---

If you only need groups where the consecutive integers are **at least** 3 you have to modify the inequality accordingly (`len(x) > 2`).

Comment: it's not working when dictionary is not ordered. For input `name_list = {0:'I', 3: 'Mr.', 5: 'Nevrekar', 8: 'JK', 14: 'Soham', 15: 'Sharma', 4: 'Akshay'}`

Comment: Thanks :-) This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples):

```
>>> a = {0:'I', 3: 'Mr.', 4: 'Akshay', 5: 'Nevrekar', 8: 'JK', 14: 'Soham', 15: 'Sharma'}
>>>
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> con_ser = None
>>> for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted(a.keys())), lambda (i,x):i-x):
...     item = map(itemgetter(1), g)
...     if(len(item) >= 3):
...             con_ser = item
...             break
... 
>>> 
>>> [a.get(x) for x in con_ser] .        #con_ser = [3, 4, 5]
['Mr.', 'Akshay', 'Nevrekar']
>>>
```

Comment: getting invalid syntax at `lambda (i,x):i-x`

Comment: I've copied the code from my terminal. Should work for you. I'm on python 2.7