# How to find the groups of consecutive elements in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have to cluster the consecutive elements from a NumPy array. Considering the following example

```
a = [ 0, 47, 48, 49, 50, 97, 98, 99]
```

The output should be a list of tuples as follows

```
[(0), (47, 48, 49, 50), (97, 98, 99)]
```

Here the difference is just one between the elements. It will be great if the difference can also be specified as a limit or a hardcoded number.

Comment: I found this answer having EXACTELY the same problem... Small world! :o)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

Comment: See also: https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/01/grouping-into-runs-of-adjacent-values.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a lil func that might help:

```
def group_consecutives(vals, step=1):
    """Return list of consecutive lists of numbers from vals (number list)."""
    run = []
    result = [run]
    expect = None
    for v in vals:
        if (v == expect) or (expect is None):
            run.append(v)
        else:
            run = [v]
            result.append(run)
        expect = v + step
    return result

>>> group_consecutives(a)
[[0], [47, 48, 49, 50], [97, 98, 99]]
>>> group_consecutives(a, step=47)
[[0, 47], [48], [49], [50, 97], [98], [99]]
```

P.S. This is pure Python. For a NumPy solution, see unutbu's answer.

Comment: P.S. If you want tuples instead of lists, you can do `tuple(map(tuple, group_consecutives(a)))`

Comment: This is not a NumPy solution!

Comment: This should be much slower than the answer using `np.split`.

Answer (score 238):

```
def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

a = np.array([0, 47, 48, 49, 50, 97, 98, 99])
consecutive(a)
```

yields

```
[array([0]), array([47, 48, 49, 50]), array([97, 98, 99])]
```

Comment: And for finding runs of identical strings: `partitions = np.where(a[1:] != a[:-1])[0] + 1` (`np.diff` doesn't work for strings)

Comment: Thank you! And if we use `np.split(np.r_[:len(data)], np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)` we get contiguous index lists, so if `data` is one column of a big table, we could use that result to index the same groups of rows.

Comment: @unutbu May I know what has to be changed in this function if I want to select only the groups with at least 5 consecutive elements?

Answer (score 13):

`(a[1:]-a[:-1])==1`  will produce a boolean array where `False` indicates breaks in the runs.  You can also use the built-in [numpy.grad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html).

Comment: I don't understand this answer although it's the only one that looks "functional" (as in functional language). What you are doing here is apply the minus operator to list. I don't see how could that work.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker It's not functional.  `a` in this case is a numpy array, not a list and the minus operator does element-wise subtraction.

Answer (score 6):

**Tested for one dimensional arrays**

Get where *diff* isn't one

```
diffs = numpy.diff(array) != 1
```

Get the indexes of diffs, grab the first dimension and add one to all because *diff* compares with the previous index

```
indexes = numpy.nonzero(diffs)[0] + 1
```

Split with the given indexes

```
groups = numpy.split(array, indexes)
```

Answer (score 5):

this is what I came up so far: not sure is 100% correct

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 0, 47, 48, 49, 50, 97, 98, 99])
print np.split(a, np.cumsum( np.where(a[1:] - a[:-1] > 1) )+1)
```

returns:

```
>>>[array([0]), array([47, 48, 49, 50]), array([97, 98, 99])]
```

Comment: Counter example: a = np.array([ 0, 47, 48, 49, 50, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 140, 141]) print(np.split(a, np.cumsum( np.where(a[1:] - a[:-1] > 1) )+1)) produces [array([0]), array([47, 48, 49, 50]), array([ 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 140]), array([141]), array([], dtype=int64)]

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that instead of `np.split`, list comprehension is more performative. So the below function (almost like [@unutbu's `consecutive` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/17521785) except it uses a list comprehension to split the array) is much faster:

```
def consecutive_w_list_comprehension(arr, stepsize=1):
    idx = np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(arr) != stepsize)[0]+1, len(arr)]
    return [arr[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:])]
```

For example, for an array of length 100_000, `consecutive_w_list_comprehension` is over 4x faster:

```
arr = np.sort(np.random.choice(range(150000), size=100000, replace=False))

%timeit -n 100 consecutive(arr)
96.1 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 consecutive_w_list_comprehension(arr)
23.2 ms ± 858 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In fact, this relationship holds up no matter the size of the array. The plot below shows the runtime difference between the answers on here.

[image]

Code used to produce the plot above:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

def consecutive_w_list_comprehension(arr, stepsize=1):
    idx = np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(arr) != stepsize)[0]+1, len(arr)]
    return [arr[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:])]

def group_consecutives(vals, step=1):
    run = []
    result = [run]
    expect = None
    for v in vals:
        if (v == expect) or (expect is None):
            run.append(v)
        else:
            run = [v]
            result.append(run)
        expect = v + step
    return result


def JozeWs(array):
    diffs = np.diff(array) != 1
    indexes = np.nonzero(diffs)[0] + 1
    groups = np.split(array, indexes)
    return groups

perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n: np.sort(np.random.choice(range(2*n), size=n, replace=False)),
    kernels = [consecutive, consecutive_w_list_comprehension, group_consecutives, JozeWs],
    labels = ['consecutive', 'consecutive_w_list_comprehension', 'group_consecutives', 'JozeWs'],
    n_range = [2 ** k for k in range(5, 22)],
    equality_check = lambda *lst: all((x==y).all() for x,y in zip(*lst)),
    xlabel = '~len(arr)'
)
```

Answer (score -4):

This sounds a little like homework, so if you dont mind I will suggest an approach

You can iterate over a list using

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i]
```

You could test the next element in the list meets some criteria like follows

```
if a[i] == a[i] + 1:
    print "it must be a consecutive run"
```

And you can store results seperately in

```
results = []
```

Beware - there is an index out of range error hidden in the above you will need to deal with

Comment: Please don't suggest using python iterators over numpy arrays when more obvious solutions exist.  It defeats the purpose of using numpy.  (usually.)  If the OP did not care about performance, they probably would have used a python list.