# Describing gaps in a time series pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I'm trying to write a function that takes a continuous time series and returns a data structure which describes any missing gaps in the data (e.g. a DF with columns 'start' and 'end'). It seems like a fairly common issue for time series, but despite messing around with groupby, diff, and the like -- and exploring SO -- I haven't been able to come up with much better than the below.

It's a priority for me that this use vectorized operations to remain efficient. There has got to be a more obvious solution using vectorized operations -- hasn't there? Thanks for any help, folks.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_gaps(series):
    """
    @param series: a continuous time series of data with the index's freq set
    @return: a series where the index is the start of gaps, and the values are
         the ends
    """
    missing = series.isnull()
    different_from_last = missing.diff()

    # any row not missing while the last was is a gap end        
    gap_ends = series[~missing & different_from_last].index

    # count the start as different from the last
    different_from_last[0] = True

    # any row missing while the last wasn't is a gap start
    gap_starts = series[missing & different_from_last].index        

    # check and remedy if series ends with missing data
    if len(gap_starts) > len(gap_ends):
         gap_ends = gap_ends.append(series.index[-1:] + series.index.freq)

    return pd.Series(index=gap_starts, data=gap_ends)
```

For the record, Pandas==0.13.1, Numpy==1.8.1, Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be transformed to find the continuous numbers in a list. find all the indices where the series is null, and if a run of (3,4,5,6) are all null, you only need to extract the start and end (3,6)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby


# create an example 
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
s = pd.series( data, index=data)
s = s.reindex(xrange(18))
print find_gap(s)  


def find_gap(s): 
    """ just treat it as a list
    """ 
    nullindex = np.where( s.isnull())[0]
    ranges = []
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(nullindex), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
        ranges.append((group[0], group[-1]))
    startgap, endgap = zip(* ranges) 
    return pd.series( endgap, index= startgap )
```

reference : [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

Comment: Thanks -- you're definitely right that there are great itertools, etc. solutions for this. I should've been clearer though that I'm really hoping to keep this on the numpy level to afford as much optimization as possible. Also, I'm not sure this is really a cleaner solution than the above.

Comment: maybe you want to check out this solution :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352684/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-from-an-array-in-numpy the one by unutbu