# How to split list of unknown length into multiple lists by breaks in the consecutive sequence of the integers in python?

Tags: python, list, range, list-comprehension

I am trying to split a list of unknown length into multiple lists based on the difference between elements in the list in python. The list contains consecutive integers until a "break" occurs, and another set of consecutive integers begins. I have been trying to get the syntax right with a very basic example, but have had some trouble:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13]
```

Ideally I'd like to break this into two lists:

`b = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `c = [9,10,11,12,13]` based on the difference between elements 5 and 9 in the list.

I have tried using different forms of list comprehension, but haven't gotten the commands quite right.

```
b = [e for e in a if e+1 - e == 1]
```

print b

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13]
```

When I thought it would return b=[1,2,3,4,5]

Any insight would be great. I have been searching around and just have not found a way to reliably split the list by the occurrence and an unknown break in the sequence of numbers. I have considered manipulating the range() function in conjunction with remove() or del() to get ride of the parts that I do not need in the list, but haven't found a workable way to do it using those functions either. I am a novice programmer that works mainly in the arcpy module for arcgis, and have limited actual programming experience outside of working in arcgis.

Comment: difference bigger than 1, you want to split?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352684/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-from-an-array-in-numpy

Comment: Why would `e+1 - e` not be `1` ?

Comment: The answers in the duplicate would split into list of lists.

Comment: @teasu - yes, if the difference is bigger than 1 in the series, I want to be able to split into different lists