# Filtering pandas or numpy arrays for continuous series with minimum window length

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, scipy

I would like to filter a `numpy` `array` (or `pandas` `DataFrame`) in a way that only continuous series of the same value with at least `window_size` length is kept and everything else set to 0.

For example:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
```

should become when using a window size of 4

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

I've tried using `rolling_apply` and `scipy.ndimage.filtes.gerneric_filter` but due to the nature of rolling kernel functions I don't think it is the right approach here (and I am stuck with it at the moment).

I insert my attempt here anyway:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
#from scipy import ndimage
df= pd.DataFrame({'x':np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])})
df_alt = df.copy()
def filter_df(df, colname, window_size):
    rolling_func = lambda z: z.sum() >= window_size
    df[colname] = pd.rolling_apply(df[colname],
                                    window_size,
                                    rolling_func,
                                    min_periods=window_size/2,
                                    center = True) 

def filter_alt(df, colname, window_size):
    rolling_func = lambda z: z.sum() >= window_size
    return scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(df[colname].values,
                                                rolling_func,
                                                size = window_size,                                       
                                                origin = 0)

window_size = 4
filter_df(df, 'x', window_size)
print df
filter_alt(df_alt, 'x', window_size)
```

Comment: How would you like to treat a sequence of same values longer than the window size? Are the values always identical or can they differ for the same array?

Comment: I would like to keep them as a series of 1 too. Like: [1,1,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is basically an [`image closing operation in image-processing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) for a 1D case though. Such operations could be implemented with convolution methods. Now, [`NumPy does support 1D convolution`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), so we are in luck! Thus, to solve our case, it would be something like this -

```
def conv_app(A, WSZ):
    K = np.ones(WSZ,dtype=int)
    L = WSZ-1
    return (np.convolve(np.convolve(A,K)>=WSZ,K)[L:-L]>0).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [581]: A
Out[581]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [582]: conv_app(A,4)
Out[582]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [583]: A = np.append(1,A) # Append 1 and see what happens!

In [584]: A
Out[584]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [585]: conv_app(A,4)
Out[585]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Runtime tests -

This section benchmarks couple of other approaches listed to solve the posted question. Their definitions are listed below -

```
def groupby_app(A,WSZ): # @lambo477's solution
    groups = itertools.groupby(A)
    result = []
    for group in groups:
        group_items = [item for item in group[1]]
        group_length = len(group_items)
        if group_length >= WSZ:
            result.extend([item for item in group_items])
        else:
            result.extend([0]*group_length)
    return result

def stride_tricks_app(arr, window): # @ajcr's solution
    x = pd.rolling_min(arr, window)
    x[:window-1] = 0
    y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (len(x)-window+1, window), (8, 8))
    y[y[:, -1] == 1] = 1
    return x.astype(int)
```

Timings -

```
In [541]: A = np.random.randint(0,2,(100000))

In [542]: WSZ = 4

In [543]: %timeit groupby_app(A,WSZ)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.5 ms per loop

In [544]: %timeit stride_tricks_app(A,WSZ)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop

In [545]: %timeit conv_app(A,WSZ)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: I should have known that you'd find a fast way! I thought briefly about convolution, but didn't think about applying it twice. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.groupby` as follows:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])
window_size = 4

groups = itertools.groupby(my_array)

result = []
for group in groups:
    group_items = [item for item in group[1]]
    group_length = len(group_items)
    if group_length >= window_size:
        result.extend([item for item in group_items])
    else:
        result.extend([0]*group_length)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This is also a good solution and I believe a slight bit faster than the one I provided.

Comment: Thanks lambo Ill test your solution too and see which performs better.

Comment: itertools groupby is surprisingly fast on my rather big dataframes. I tested 10000 iterations against johnchase solution and it performed a lot better memory and runtime wise. So I'll consider this the better solution. Although john's looks quite nice but lacks performance. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `pd.rolling_min` and stride tricks:

```
def func(arr, window):
    x = pd.rolling_min(arr, window)
    x[:window-1] = 0
    y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (len(x)-window+1, window), (8, 8))
    y[y[:, -1] == 1] = 1
    return x.astype(int)
```

Then we have:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])
>>> func(x, 4)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> y = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]) # five 1s
>>> func(y, 4)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

On large arrays, this approach is fairly quick (on my system groupby is around 20 times slower):

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=1000000)
>>> %timeit func(x, 4)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes ajcr I've tried it and it was the slowest. The itertools solution is by far the fastest. Aroung 13.9 ms per loop on my dataset, Johns take around 153 ms per loop and yours nearly 3 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: @pho: I replaced `rolling_apply` with `rolling_min` just after I asked (I'd pasted the wrong function - apologies). It should be significantly faster on any larger dataset.

Comment: I also had an error in my modified groupby function which explains it is that fast. Ill test it all tomorrow once again. Thank you ajcr

Comment: @pho Added runtime tests [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34620926/3293881). `Groupby` method does seem a lot slower compared to strides method.

Answer (score 1):

There may very well be a better solution, however I think this should work:

```
In [90]: x = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,2,1,4,4,4,4,4,0,1,1,1,1])
```

I included some other numbers in there just in case you need code that accounts for that;

```
In [93]: y = np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0]+1)
         z = [list(e) if len(e) >= 4 else [0]*len(e) for e in y]
         result = np.array([item for sublist in z for item in sublist])
```

The first line here is splitting the original array into consecutive characters, the second line replaces any item that contains less than 4 consecutive characters with 0s and the final line flattens the split list.

```
In [96]: result
Out[96]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The first line of the solution also makes extensive use of a previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/3639023)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks quite elegant I'll try it on my data set and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

A more compact variation on the `itertools.groupby` solution:

```
window_size = 4
groups = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(my_array)]
filtered_array = [g if sum(g) >= window_size else [0]*len(g) for g in groups]
[int(i) for sub in filtered_array for i in sub]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```