# Split list into groups of sequential numbers

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
test = [1,2,3,4,65,66,67,68,69,72,85,86,87,88,89,91]
```

I want to return multiple lists with sequential numbers:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[65,66,67,68,69]
[72]
[85,86,87,88,89]
[91]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

Comment: did you try anything already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352684/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-from-an-array-in-numpy