# group list elements by their difference with respect to each other

Tags: python, list, grouping

Given a list

```
A = [1, 6, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 29, 36, 53, 58, 59, 61, 63, 78, 79, 81, 102, 114]
```

is there an easy way to group all those clusters where the difference between successive elements is smaller than 3?

That is, obtain something like:

```
[13, 15, 17, 19, 21], [58, 59, 61, 63], [78, 79, 81]
```

I was wondering whether there exists any built-in function, but I couldn't find anything similar. I was trying to figure it out using the `groupby` of the `itertools`, but I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So are you ignoring any group with less than 3 elements?

Comment: Well, I'm not ignoring them. In this array just there weren't two stand-alone elements whose difference was less than 3. If there were, it was ok to group them too. I'm looking for something like an "until" or "while" the difference is X, then group them.

Comment: So, 1 and 6 should not be considered singleton clusters?

Comment: It's not necessary. But if you want you can keep them as singleton clusters and I can neglect them in a second moment on the basis of their length. The important thing is to "store elements until" the condition is satisfied :)

Comment: regarding "store elements until" `itertools.takewhile` does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
A = [1, 6, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 29, 36, 53, 58, 59, 61, 63, 78, 79, 81, 102, 114]
new_a = [(A[i+1]-A[i], A[i]) for i in range(len(A)-1)]
a = [[a, [c for _, c in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_a, key=lambda x:x[0] < 3)]
final_groups = [a[i][-1]+[a[i+1][-1][0]] if a[i+1][-1][0] - a[i][-1][-1] < 3 else a[i][-1] for i in range(len(a)-1) if a[i][0]]
```

Output:

```
[[13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21], [58, 59, 61, 63], [78, 79, 81]]
```

Comment: hi Ajax, I test your solution with `A = [25,26,53,54,55,56]`, but the results is `[[25, 26]]`. I think you have a bug in your solution

Comment: I think this is a really smooth idea. However, I think the final_groups call is faulty. My suggestion would be to have the second index of new_a have the tuple (A[i],A[i+1]) instead of just A[i] and replacing final_groups with something like 

[[t[1][0][0]] + [q[-1] for q in t[1]] for t in a if t[0]]

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using an iteration.

**Ex:**

```
A = [1, 6, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 29, 36, 53, 58, 59, 61, 63, 78, 79, 81, 102, 114]
res = []
temp = []
l = len(A)-1

for i,v in enumerate(A):
    if i+1 > l:
        break

    if abs(v - A[i+1]) < 3:
        temp.append(v)
    else:
        if temp:
            temp.append(v)
            res.append(temp)
            temp = []
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21], [58, 59, 61, 63], [78, 79, 81]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/4042267), which asked for runs of the same number, one can use `numpy.split` here:

```
import numpy as np

def plateaus(A, atol=3):
    runs = np.split(A, np.where(np.abs(np.diff(A)) >= atol)[0] + 1)
    return [list(x) for x in runs if len(x) > 1]

A = [1, 6, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 29, 36, 53, 58, 59, 61, 63, 78, 79, 81, 102, 114]
print(plateaus(A))
[[13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21], [58, 59, 61, 63], [78, 79, 81]]
```

Without filtering on the length, this gives you singleton clusters just like [the `itertools.takehwile` approach by @sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212264/4042267).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> The important thing is to "store elements until" the condition is satisfied

You could use `itertools.takewhile` for this.

> takewhile(predicate, iterable) --> takewhile object
>
> Return successive entries from an iterable as long as the
>   predicate evaluates to true for each entry.

This solution certainly has room for improvement, but the takeaway is the use of `takewhile`

```
class Grouper:
    """simple class to perform comparison when called, storing last element given"""
    def __init__(self, diff):
        self.last = None
        self.diff = diff
    def predicate(self, item):
        if self.last is None:
            return True
        return abs(self.last - item) < self.diff
    def __call__(self, item):
        """called with each item by takewhile"""
        result = self.predicate(item)
        self.last = item
        return result


def group_by_difference(items, diff=3):
    results = []
    start = 0
    remaining_items = items
    while remaining_items:
        g = Grouper(diff)
        group = [*itertools.takewhile(g, remaining_items)]
        results.append(group)
        start += len(group)
        remaining_items = items[start:]
    return results
```

This gives you grouped items with singleton clusters.

```
[[1],
 [6],
 [13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21],
 [29],
 [36],
 [53],
 [58, 59, 61, 63],
 [78, 79, 81],
 [102],
 [114]]
```