# Dataframe find & remove non changing values multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I'm struggeling with some data massaging process. 
I'm thinking of a best way to find and remove non-changing entries in dataframe.

I have signal level data that comes from mobile device

```
measDate    measLatitude    measLongitude   measCellId  measNetTypeDetail   measOperatorCode    measSignalLevel
2019-06-05 00:22:10.791     27.676038   84.177025   14603   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:11.806     27.676038   84.177025   14603   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:14.179     27.676038   84.177025   14604   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:14.279     27.676038   84.177025   14604   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:16.657     27.676038   84.177025   14604   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:18.904     27.676038   84.177025   14615   13  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:21.276     27.676038   84.177025   14615   13  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:23.557     27.676038   84.177025   14614   13  42902   -95 
2019-06-05 00:22:24.796     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:26.768     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:27.787     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:28.802     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:31.803     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:33.799     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96
```

so basically signalLevel and some associated data + timestamp

What I need to do is to filter data in following way:

- if signal level does not change for the past n-samples (eg. n=3 samples)
- if other values does not change as well
- filter-out the data.

**So in the end I'd like to have maximum n-same-samples in row.**

Expected results with WINDOW N=3

```
measDate    measLatitude    measLongitude   measCellId  measNetTypeDetail   measOperatorCode    measSignalLevel
2019-06-05 00:22:10.791     27.676038   84.177025   14603   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:11.806     27.676038   84.177025   14603   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:14.179     27.676038   84.177025   14604   13  42902   -97 
2019-06-05 00:22:18.904     27.676038   84.177025   14615   13  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:21.276     27.676038   84.177025   14615   13  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:23.557     27.676038   84.177025   14614   13  42902   -95 
2019-06-05 00:22:24.796     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:26.768     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96 
2019-06-05 00:22:27.787     27.676038   84.177025   14603   10  42902   -96
```

I've came to this code after some tests. I try to check if any of the columns value changed by checking unique values within window per column (here window size =3) then I sum if any of the column changed then I need to keep it

```
RadioSmall = RadioMeasAll.loc[:,['measLatitude','measLongitude','measCellId','measNetTypeDetail','measOperatorCode','measCid','measLac','measSignalLevel','cellArfcn']].copy()

def f(x):
    y = x[~np.isnan(x)]
    if len(np.unique(y)) > 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

a = RadioSmall.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(f,raw=True)
a['sum']=a.sum(axis=1)
b = pd.DataFrame(index=a.index)
b['filtering'] = a['sum']
df_filtered =  b.query('filtering>0')

RadioMeasAll.join(df_filtered)
```

Looks very ugly to me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796) - please post a subset of your actual data, not screenshots of data, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks @w-m for pointing that out. I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

cols_to_compare = df.columns.drop(['measDate'])  # Columns where the values will be compared
window_size = 3

has_change = df[cols_to_compare].diff().any(axis=1)
df = df[has_change.rolling(window_size).apply(np.any, raw=True).fillna(1, downcast="bool")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand your goal now.

```
df.reset_index(drop=False) # I want to opearte on integer indices
a = df.index[(df[columns] == df[columns].shift()).all(axis=1)]
```

`a` is an array containing indices of consecutive rows that have values of `columns` equal to the following row (it ommits the FIRST occurrence).

Now we should split it into subsets of consecutive indices, (idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352684/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-from-an-array-in-numpy))

```
duplicate_groups = np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0] + 1)
```

`duplicate_groups` now contains arrays of consecutive indices. You can now filter for consectuive duplicates longer than N, let's say `N = 5`.

```
[arr for arr in duplicate_groups if len(arr) > 4] # 4 b/c we ommitted FIRST occurrence
```

Try to run it on your data and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I understand columns is an array of columns to be checked. but what is id_ ?
I've edited my post with my sample code and replicable set

Comment: Sorry, `id_` was supposed to be `a`

Comment: after you run first two lines, what does `a` contain ?

Comment: a returns empty `[]`
`columns = ['measLatitude','measLongitude','measCellId','measNetTypeDetail','measOperatorCode','measLac','measSignalLevel','cellArfcn']
df.reset_index(drop=False)
a = df.index[(df[columns] == df[columns].shift()).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Is any of these columns in float? Change your `columns` variable so it only has `measSignalLevel` and see then, then add more columns and check which one makes a to be empty

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary dataframe sharing same index as the original one to compute the groups of consecutive values, their size and the rank of a row in its group.

Then I would only keep in the original dataframe the rows having a rank below the window:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)                     # tmp dataframe with same index
tmp['dup'] = df[df.columns[1:].tolist()].duplicated()  # duplicated rows (except for datetime)
# define groups of consecutive rows
tmp.loc[~tmp['dup'],'change'] = 1               
tmp['group'] = tmp['change'].cumsum()
tmp['group'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# compute ranks in groups 
tmp['rank'] = tmp.groupby('group').cumcount()

# extract a filtered dataframe
filtered = df.loc[tmp['rank'] < 3]
```

It gives as expected:

```
                  measDate  measLatitude  measLongitude  measCellId  measNetTypeDetail  measOperatorCode  measSignalLevel
0  2019-06-05 00:22:10.791     27.676038      84.177025       14603                 13             42902              -97
1  2019-06-05 00:22:11.806     27.676038      84.177025       14603                 13             42902              -97
2  2019-06-05 00:22:14.179     27.676038      84.177025       14604                 13             42902              -97
3  2019-06-05 00:22:14.279     27.676038      84.177025       14604                 13             42902              -97
4  2019-06-05 00:22:16.657     27.676038      84.177025       14604                 13             42902              -97
5  2019-06-05 00:22:18.904     27.676038      84.177025       14615                 13             42902              -96
6  2019-06-05 00:22:21.276     27.676038      84.177025       14615                 13             42902              -96
7  2019-06-05 00:22:23.557     27.676038      84.177025       14614                 13             42902              -95
8  2019-06-05 00:22:24.796     27.676038      84.177025       14603                 10             42902              -96
9  2019-06-05 00:22:26.768     27.676038      84.177025       14603                 10             42902              -96
10 2019-06-05 00:22:27.787     27.676038      84.177025       14603                 10             42902              -96
```

Note: if in the original dataframe the date time was the index instead of being a column, the definition of the duplicates would change to:

```
tmp['dup'] = df.duplicated()  # duplicated rows
```