# Replace consecutive identic elements in the beginning of an array with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to replace the N first identic consecutive numbers from an array with `0`.

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

OUT -> `np.array([0, 0, 0, 0 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2])`

Loop works, but what would be a faster-vectorized implementation?

```
i = 0
first = x[0]
while x[i] == first and i <= x.size - 1:
    x[i] = 0
    i += 1
```

Comment: maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352684/how-to-find-the-groups-of-consecutive-elements-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: @Glauco I gave it a try, I don't see the correct way to use this element-wise subtraction, or `np.diff` or `np.gradient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) on a boolean array to get the index of the first changing value.

Then slice and replace:

```
n = (x!=x[0]).argmax()  # 4
x[:n] = 0
```

output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

intermediate array:

```
(x!=x[0])

#                            n=4
# [False False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on *itertools.groupby*, so start from `import itertools`.

This function creates groups of **consecutive** equal values, contrary to e.g.
the pandasonic version of *groupby*, which collects withis a single group **all**
equal values from the input.

Another important feature is that you can assign any value to *N* and
replaced will be **only** the first *N* of a sequence of consecutive values.

To test my code, I set `N = 4` and defined the source array as:

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Note that it contains 5 consecutive values of *2* at the end.

Then, to get the expected result, run:

```
rv = []
for key, grp in itertools.groupby(x):
    lst = list(grp)
    lgth = len(lst)
    if lgth >= N:
        lst[0:N] = [0] * N
    rv.extend(lst)
xNew = np.array(rv)
```

The result is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Note that a sequence of 4 zeroes occurs:

- at the beginning (all 4 values of *1* have been replaced),
- almost at the end (from 5 values of *2* first 4 have been replaced).