# How to convert consecutive Trues in a 3D array into integer values representing the length of that consecutive group

Tags: python

I have a (61,77,365) numpy array full of boolean values.

Taking a random slice across axis 2 (len=365) for illustrative purposes:

*data = [False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
**True** False False False False  **True** False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False False False False False  **True  True** False False False
**True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True** False False False False
False False False False False False False False False False False False
False False False  **True  True** False False False False False False  **True
True  True  True  True  True** False False False False False False False
False False False False False  **True  True** False False False  **True** False
False False  **True  True  True** False False  **True  True** False  **True  True**
False False  **True** False  **True  True  True  True  True  True** False False
False False  **True  True  True**]*

I want to replace the True values with the length of their associated group of consecutive Trues, i.e.:

*[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0 0 **8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 **6 6 6 6 6 6** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0
0 **1** 0 0 0 **3 3 3** 0 0 **2 2** 0 **2 2** 0 0 **1** 0 **6 6 6 6 6 6** 0 0 0 0 **3 3 3**]*

How can I do this efficiently for the 3D array? I want to avoid looping as it would get very computationally expensive.

So far, I have used cumulative summing (which resets when it reaches False), and then done the same for the data reversed. Adding these together and subtracting 1 (if data=True) gives the required answer, but it's so convoluted and inefficient:

```
no_reset = np.cumsum(data,axis=axis)
reset = (data == 0)
excess = np.maximum.accumulate(no_reset*reset,axis=axis)
result = no_reset - excess
print(result)
```

*result = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2** 0 0 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2** 0 0
0 **1** 0 0 0 **1 2 3** 0 0 **1 2** 0 **1 2** 0 0 **1** 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6** 0 0 0 0 **1 2 3**]*

```
no_reset_rev = np.cumsum(data_hits[..., ::-1],axis=axis)
reset_rev = (data_hits[..., ::-1] == 0)
excess_rev = np.maximum.accumulate(no_reset_rev*reset_rev,axis=axis)
result_rev = no_reset_rev - excess_rev
print(result_rev)
```

*result_rev = [**1 2 3** 0 0 0 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6** 0 **1** 0 0 **1 2** 0 **1 2** 0 0 **1 2 3** 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 **1 2** 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6** 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8** 0 0 0 **1 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]*

```
final_res = result + result_rev[..., ::-1] - (1*data_hits)
print(final_res)
```

*final_res = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0 0 **8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 **6 6 6 6 6 6** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2 2** 0 0
0 **1** 0 0 0 **3 3 3** 0 0 **2 2** 0 **2 2** 0 0 **1** 0 **6 6 6 6 6 6** 0 0 0 0 **3 3 3**]*

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: How much slower is using "looping"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is faster but you can try this way. First, since your array is already in numpy, you can use `np.where` to change the boolean to 0 and 1.

```
myarray = np.where(data == True,1,0)
```

Next, you need to get the index of the 1's using `np.where` or `np.nonzero` (If you try it in your full array, `np.nonzero` will be faster than `np.where`.)

```
indexes = np.nonzero(myarray == 1)
```

With this, we will use a function posted by Unutbu to split the indexes based on the consecutive values. The link is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/16836078

```
def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

split_index = consecutive(indexes[0])
```

For the last part, I apologize if this is not your requirement, we will use a for loop to assign the accumulated number of the consecutive values to the original array.

```
for i in split_index:
    number = len(i)
    myarray[i] = number

myarray

array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
       2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3])
```

### Extra

I have tried to use your full array to do the operations. Looks like there're a few things to be changed.

While finding the indexes of the 1's and using the `consecutive` function, you can use list comprehension.

```
indexes = [np.nonzero(j == 1)[0] for i in abc for j in i] 
split_index = [consecutive(i) for i in indexes]
```

Finally, there's a nested for loop to assign the values to the original array.

```
split_index_arrary = np.reshape(61,77,14)

for dimension1, i in enumerate(split_index_array):
    for dimension2, j in enumerate(i):
        for k in j:
            numbers = len(k)
            myarray[dimension1][dimension2][k] = numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to get the indices at which the Trues are present along with the length of the Trues.

First create a dataframe from the data like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data})
```

You can first get cumulative sum of the Trues, False by using this trick:

```
tf = (df['data'] != df['data'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Then create another dataframe for only `True` values like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tf[df['data']])
```

Then reset index so you get the indices at which the values are True (this is important) and group and agg the list of indices:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'trues'}).groupby('data',as_index=False).agg(list)
```

Then get the length of each list

```
df2['data'] = df2['trues'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
```

Then explode by the list

```
df2 = df2.explode('trues')
```

Then set index and remove the name so you can locate it in your original df and assign properly

```
df2 = df2.set_index('trues', drop=True)
df2.index.name = ''
```

Now assign the values in original df

```
df.iloc[df2.index] = df2['data']
```

All code is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data})
tf = (df['data'] != df['data'].shift()).cumsum()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tf[df['data']])
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'trues'}).groupby('data',as_index=False).agg(list)
df2['data'] = df2['trues'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
df2 = df2.explode('trues')
df2 = df2.set_index('trues', drop=True)
df2.index.name = ''
df.iloc[df2.index] = df2['data']
```

Your final answer is in `df['data']`