# group together consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I have an ordered Python list of forms:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

How can I group together consecutive numbers in a list. A group like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23,], [30], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

I tried using groupby from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306594/python-splitting-a-datetime-list-based-on-missing-days) but was not able to tailor it to my need.
Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using groupby from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306594/python-splitting-a-datetime-list-based-on-missing-days)

Comment: But not able to tailor it to my use

Comment: loop through the list and update a sublist when array[i-1] = array[i] + 1, then append the sublist when the difference is > 1

Comment: Perhaps re-phrasing the question as "I want to group together consecutive numbers in a list" might help show how you'd implement it yourself. Without showing any code you've written its hard to suggest what to fix or change

Comment: ```res = [ lst[0] ]\
for i in range(1, len(lst)):\
  if lst[i] - 1 == lst[i-1]:\
    res[-1].append(lst[i])\
  else:\
    res.append([lst[i]])```

Comment: @user3928155 Please don't put full answers in the comments, if you've written out a solution just create an answer that way op can accept it and we all know he no longer needs help.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list

Comment: Do you have a fixed group size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use negative indexing:

```
def group_by_missing(seq):
    if not seq:
        return seq
    grouped = [[seq[0]]]
    for x in seq[1:]:
        if x == grouped[-1][-1] + 1:
            grouped[-1].append(x)
        else:
            grouped.append([x])
    return grouped
```

**Example Usage:**

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
>>> group_by_missing(lst)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A fancy pythonic way to do it with less lines would be possible with the `reduce` function from functools and a lambda function with an inline if as a criteria for the reduce:

```py
import functools
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x,y : x[:-1]+[x[-1]+[y]] if (x[-1][-1]+1==y) else [*x,[y]], lis[1:] , [[lis[0]]] )
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another even more succinct way to do this, using the `itertools` package:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def group_consecutive(l: list[int]) -> list[list]:
    "Group consecutive numbers in a list."
    return [list(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x, c=count(): x-next(c))]
```