# Use itertools.groupby (or a neet, pythonic way) to group a list by the difference between the consecutive numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

But my question is a little different:

For example:

```
[0.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 5.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10.0]
```

should gave me:

```
[[0.0], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9], [5.0], [9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10.0]]
```

All the types of them is `float`.The difference of each element of sub list should smaller than 0.1.

I try to solve it **without using third party module.**(Not homework, just a practice for python)

What I have tried: too much code with `itertools.groupby`(Couldn't solve it).One of my attempt:

```
import itertools

lst = [0.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 5.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10]

res = []
for _, item in itertools.groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda index_num: index_num[0]-index_num[1]):
    print(list(item)) # Not expected. The solution I mentioned didn't work.
```

I want a neat, pythonic way to solve it.Any tricks are welcomed, I just want to learn more skills.:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group consecutive integers and tolerate gaps of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142231/group-consecutive-integers-and-tolerate-gaps-of-1) , in @jonrsharpe solution change `if next_ > current + tol + 1:` to `if next_ > current + tol + 0.1:` you will get your answer

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thanks, What's the time complexity of his solution? Is it `O(n)`?