# Adding data to an array instead of print?

Tags: python, list, lambda, group-by, enumerate

So I found a great answer to a prblem i was having here:
[Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list).

my code is now:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(cycles), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

which gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5]
[1, 2]
```

which is great.

However I want to be able to do stuff with this info. How do I write this to an array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it as follows:

```
result = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(cycles), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    result.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))

print result
```

Or just use list comprehension:

```
result = [map(itemgetter(1), g) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(cycles), lambda (i,x):i-x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns a list in Python 2. So, you can simply assign to a variable and start using it

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(cycles), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    current_list = map(itemgetter(1), g)
    # use current_list
```