# How to reduce a collection of ranges to a minimal set of ranges

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list, range

I'm trying to remove overlapping values from a collection of ranges.

The ranges are represented by a string like this:

`499-505 100-115 80-119 113-140 500-550`

I want the above to be reduced to two ranges: `80-140 499-550`. That covers all the values without overlap.

Currently I have the following code.

```
cr = "100-115 115-119 113-125 80-114 180-185 500-550 109-120 95-114 200-250".split(" ")
ar = []
br = []

for i in cr:
    (left,right) = i.split("-")
    ar.append(left);
    br.append(right);

inc = 0
for f in br:    

    i = int(f)
    vac = []
    jnc = 0
    for g in ar:
        j = int(g)  
        if(i >= j):
            vac.append(j)
            del br[jnc]
            jnc += jnc 

    print vac 
    inc += inc
```

I split the array by `-` and store the range limits in `ar` and `br`. I iterate over these limits pairwise and if the `i` is at least as great as the `j`, I want to delete the element. But the program doesn't work. I expect it to produce this result: `80-125 500-550 200-250 180-185`

Comment: You're adding `jnc` (0) to itself. Do `jnc += 1` instead--and for `inc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer another solution that doesn't take time linearly proportional to the sum of the range sizes. Its running time is linearly proportional to the number of ranges.

```
def reduce(range_text):
    parts = range_text.split()
    if parts == []:
        return ''
    ranges = [ tuple(map(int, part.split('-'))) for part in parts ]
    ranges.sort()
    new_ranges = []
    left, right = ranges[0]
    for range in ranges[1:]:
        next_left, next_right = range
        if right + 1 < next_left:             # Is the next range to the right?
            new_ranges.append((left, right))  # Close the current range.
            left, right = range               # Start a new range.
        else:
            right = max(right, next_right)  # Extend the current range.
    new_ranges.append((left, right))  # Close the last range.
    return ' '.join([ '-'.join(map(str, range)) for range in new_ranges ]
```

This function works by sorting the ranges, then looking at them in order and merging consecutive ranges that intersect.

Examples:

```
print(reduce('499-505 100-115 80-119 113-140 500-550'))
# => 80-140 499-550

print(reduce('100-115 115-119 113-125 80-114 180-185 500-550 109-120 95-114 200-250'))
# => 80-125 180-185 200-250 500-550
```

Answer (score 6):

For a quick and short solution,

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

cr = "499-505 100-115 80-119 113-140 500-550".split(" ")
fullNumbers = []
for i in cr:
    a = int(i.split("-")[0])
    b = int(i.split("-")[1])
    fullNumbers+=range(a,b+1)

# Remove duplicates and sort it
fullNumbers = sorted(list(set(fullNumbers)))

# Taken From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249
def convertToRanges(data):
    result = []
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
        result.append(str(group[0])+"-"+str(group[-1]))
    return result

print convertToRanges(fullNumbers)
#Output: ['80-140', '499-550']
```

For the given set in your program, output is `['80-125', '180-185', '200-250', '500-550']`
Main Possible drawback of this solution: This may not be scalable!