# Grouping by multiple parameters using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, enumerate

I have a data frame that I would like to group by two parameters (1) consecutive numbering in the same first column and (2) matching values in the second column

data frame:

```
In [20]: import pandas as pd

In [21]: df1 = pd.DataFrame ({ "res": [30, 31, 35, 36], "ss": ["H", "H", "H", "E"], "AA": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})

In [22]: df1
Out[22]:
   res ss AA
0  30  H  A
1  31  H  B
2  35  H  C
3  36  E  D
```

Desired output:

`group 1: (30, H, A), (31, H, B)`

`group 2: (35, H, C)`

`group 3: (36, E, D)`

Group 1 includes the first 2 rows because 30 and 31 are consecutive and the second columns match. 
Group 2 is created because 31 and 35 in col 1 are not consecutive.
Group 3 is created because H and E do not match.

I am trying to use groupby and enumerate together, but I can't seem to combine them.

[Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

[grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

I appreciate any tips on how to combine the selections

Comment: I don't understand your desired output at all.  What is "AB, C, D", and how do you get it from `df1`?  Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @DSM I edited my question. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I took some liberties with what you meant.  Let me know if I understood correctly.

## Setup: copy & paste to set up problem

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame ({"res": [30, 31, 35, 36],
                     "ss": ["H", "H", "H", "E"],
                     "AA": ["A", "C", "D", "B"]})  # I made 'F' a 'B'

df1
```

`df1` looks like:

```
  AA  res ss
0  A   30  H
1  C   31  H
2  D   35  H
3  B   36  E
```

I believe you just want to `sort` not `groupby`.

## Solution

```
print df1.sort_values(['AA', 'res'])
```

Looks like:

```
  AA  res ss
0  A   30  H
3  B   36  E
1  C   31  H
2  D   35  H
```

However, parts of your question don't make sense.  Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the columns. Column 1 should have numbers. Column two should have either "H" or "E" and the last column should have letters. I want to create groups where the first columns are consecutive and the second column matches.. i.e 30, H, A and 31, H, B for one group. 35, H, D is a new group because 31 and 35 are not consecutive. 36, E, C would be a new group because H and E do not match.