# Subdividing python integer list into groups of linearly spaced items

Tags: python, algorithm, list, numpy, tuples

Suppose i have to following list, it is guaranteed to be sorted and have no duplicates:

```
In [224]: a=[0,2,4,8,12,16,20,21,30,33,36]
```

I want to subdivide it to form a nested tuple in which each item can be created using range or np.arange. There can sometimes be numerous grouping possibilities (two items can always form a group). I want to minimize the amount of groups containing two items.

Here is an example:

```
In [225]: to_range_group(a)
((0,2,4),(8,12,16,20),(21),(30,33,36))
```

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: *I want to minimize the amount of groups containing two items* - and how about `((0,2,4),(8,12,16,20),(21,30,33,36))` ? Should it be an ascending subdivision?

Comment: `(21,30,33,36)` can't be created using `range` or `np.arange`. It does not consistently have an increment of 3.

Comment: With a little modification, [Identify groups of varying continuous numbers in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709606/identify-groups-of-varying-continuous-numbers-in-a-list/39712094) has your answer

Comment: Oh nice, thanks, couldn't find that.