# get non-overlapping period from 2 dataframe with date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, date-range

I'm working on a billing system.

On the one hand, I have contracts with start and end date, which I need to bill monthly. One contract can have several start/end dates, but they can't overlap for a same contract.

On the other hand, I have a df with the invoice billed per contract, with their start and end date. Invoices' start/end dates for a specific contract can't also overlap. There could be gap though between end date of an invoice and start of another invoice.

My goal is to look at the contract start/end dates, and remove all the period billed for a single contract, so that I know what's left to be billed.

Here is my data for contract:

```
contract_df = pd.DataFrame({'contract_id': {0: 'C00770052',
  1: 'C00770052',
  2: 'C00770052',
  3: 'C00770052',
  4: 'C00770053'},
 'from': {0: pd.to_datetime('2018-07-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01 00:00:00')},
 'to': {0: pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.to_datetime('2024-01-01 00:00:00')}})
```

[image: contractdf]

Here is my invoice data (no invoice for C00770053):

```
 invoice_df = pd.DataFrame({'contract_id': {0: 'C00770052',
  1: 'C00770052',
  2: 'C00770052',
  3: 'C00770052',
  4: 'C00770052',
  5: 'C00770052',
  6: 'C00770052',
  7: 'C00770052'},
 'from': {0: pd.to_datetime('2018-07-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2018-09-01 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.to_datetime('2018-10-01 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.to_datetime('2018-11-01 00:00:00'),
  5: pd.to_datetime('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
  6: pd.to_datetime('2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
  7: pd.to_datetime('2019-07-01 00:00:00')},
 'to': {0: pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2018-09-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2018-10-01 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.to_datetime('2018-11-01 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
  5: pd.to_datetime('2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
  6: pd.to_datetime('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
  7: pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:00:00')}})
```

[image: invoicedf]

My expected result is:

```
to_bill_df = pd.DataFrame({'contract_id': {0: 'C00770052',
  1: 'C00770052',
  2: 'C00770053'},
 'from': {0: pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01 00:00:00')},
 'to': {0: pd.to_datetime('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.to_datetime('2024-01-01 00:00:00')}})
```

[image: tobilldf]

What I need therefore is to go through each row of contract_df, identify the invoices matching the relevant period and remove the periods which have already been billed from the contract_df, eventually splitting the contract_df row into 2 rows if there is a gap.

The problem is that going like this seem very heavy considering that I'll have millions of invoices and contracts, I feel like there is an easy way with pandas but I'm not sure how I could do it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was solving a similar problem the other day. It's not a simple solution but should be generic in identifying any non-overlapping intervals.

The idea is to convert your dates into continuous integers and then we can remove the overlap with a set OR operator. The function below will transform your DataFrame into a dictionary that contains a list of non-overlapping integer dates for each ID.

```
from functools import reduce

def non_overlapping_intervals(df, uid, date_from, date_to):
    # Convert date to day integer
    helper_from = date_from + '_helper'
    helper_to = date_to + '_helper'
    df[helper_from] = df[date_from].sub(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')).dt.days  # set a reference date
    df[helper_to] = df[date_to].sub(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')).dt.days

    out = (
        df[[uid, helper_from, helper_to]]
        .dropna()
        .groupby(uid)
        [[helper_from, helper_to]]
        .apply(
            lambda x: reduce(  # Apply for an arbitrary number of cases
                lambda a, b: a | b, x.apply(  # Eliminate the overlapping dates OR operation on set
                    lambda y: set(range(y[helper_from], y[helper_to])), # Create continuous integers for date ranges
                    axis=1
                )
            )
        )
        .to_dict()
    )
    return out
```

From here, we want to do a set subtraction to find the dates and IDs for which there are contracts but no invoices:

```
from collections import defaultdict

invoice_dates = defaultdict(set, non_overlapping_intervals(invoice_df, 'contract_id', 'from', 'to'))
contract_dates = defaultdict(set, non_overlapping_intervals(contract_df, 'contract_id', 'from', 'to'))

missing_dates = {}
for k, v in contract_dates.items():
    missing_dates[k] = list(v - invoice_dates.get(k, set()))
```

Now we have a dict called `missing_dates` that gives us each date for which there are no invoices. To convert it into your output format, we need to separate each continuous group for each ID. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154437/7489710), we arrive at the below:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

missing_invoices = []
for uid, dates in missing_dates.items():
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted(dates)), lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
        group = list(map(int, map(itemgetter(1), g)))
        missing_invoices.append([uid, group[0], group[-1]])
missing_invoices = pd.DataFrame(missing_invoices, columns=['contract_id', 'from', 'to'])

# Convert back to datetime
missing_invoices['from'] = missing_invoices['from'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(days=x))
missing_invoices['to'] = missing_invoices['to'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(days=x + 1))
```

Probably not the simple solution you were looking for, but this should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: that is very clever way of doing it, which works fine and give the expected results !
I was considering doing something similar with a df of all days to bill per contract_id and remove the duplicates with a df of all days for all invoices but it was taking too long, creating those daily df using sthg like: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'contract_id': row['contract_id'], 'from': pd.date_range(row['from'], row['to'], freq='1D', closed='left')}) for index, row in contract_df.iterrows()])

just curious if someone found a clean and fast way of doing something like this with pandas