# identify groups of ending contunious numbers from dataframe/list

Tags: python, list, range, continuous

data looks like this:

```
data=["q11-23-45","q11-23-46","q11-23-47","b11-73-50","q12-93-55","p11-23-59","p11-23-60","p11-23-61"]
```

trying to get something like:

```
q11-23-45 to 47

b11-73-50

q12-93-55

p11-23-59 to 61
```

tried

```
a=[]
b=[]
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    try:
        if int(data[i][-2:])+1!= int(data[i+1][-2:]):
            a.append(data[i])
        else:
            b.append(data[i])
    except:
        print(" out of index ")
```

tried to find solution but the given solutions like [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

it's for integers in list and not strings + integers

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
def convert(data, split_str):
    output = []
    for d_index, d in enumerate(data):
        d = str(d)
        if d_index == 0:
            same_start = [d]
            continue
        start = d.split(split_str)[0]
        last_start = data[d_index-1].split(split_str)[0]
        if start == last_start:
            same_start.append(d)
        else:
            same_start = [d]
        if same_start not in output:
            output.append(same_start)

    for single_output in output:
        if len(single_output) == 1:
            print(single_output[0])
        else:
            print(single_output[0] + " to " + str(single_output[-1]).split(split_str)[-1])


data= ["015 443 02 58",'015 443 02 59']
convert(data, " ")

print("=======")
data=["q11-23-45","q11-23-46","q11-23-47","b11-73-50","q12-93-55","p11-23-59","p11-23-60","p11-23-61"]
convert(data, "-")
```

**Output**:

```
015 443 02 58 to 59
=======    
q11-23-45 to 47
b11-73-50
q12-93-55
p11-23-59 to 61
```

Comment: small doubt @Harsh Biyani

if the list has numbers it won't work right?
example ['015 443 02 58",'015 443 02 59']

Comment: @aminsama You can convert it into string then

Comment: @aminsama: I have modified answer

Comment: thank you so much!
but can we compare the last two char rather then finding a - or " "

Comment: @aminsama: yes, we can. You can remove all alpha-numeric characters and can find out the `split_str`

Comment: I tried slicing but it didn't work. can you please guide me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict with max and min functions to achieve the desired output

```
from collections import defaultdict

data=["q11-23-45","q11-23-46","q11-23-47","b11-73-50","q12-93-55","p11-23-59","p11-23-60","p11-23-61"]

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    result[i[:i.rfind("-")]].append(i[i.rfind("-")+1:])

print(*[f"{i}-{min(result[i])} to {max(result[i])}" if max(result[i]) != min(result[i]) else f"{i}-{min(result[i])}" for i in result.keys()], sep="\n")
```

Output

```
q11-23-45 to 47
b11-73-50
q12-93-55
p11-23-59 to 61
```

This code will aggregate all items that have the same text until the last `-` the number that is coming after will be appended to the list of the dictionary item.
Then the print statement is printing all the dictionary keys with the min and max values if they are not the same else it will print just one part.

Comment: thank you so much!
but can we compare the last two char rather then finding a "-"