# Identify groups of continuous time intervals in a list

Tags: python, list, date

I have this list of date:

`dates = ['2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11', '2020-01', '2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05', '2020-09', '2020-10']`

What I want is to be able to detect that :

`['2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12']` is a continuous time interval

`['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11']` is another one

then there is

`['2020-01'`],

`['2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05']`

and `['2020-09', '2020-10']`

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: so you want a nested list of those dates?

Comment: Please provide an example of the output, one of what you've tried and explain what's not working with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, count

dates = ['2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04',
         '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11', '2020-01', '2020-03', '2020-04',
         '2020-05', '2020-09', '2020-10']
counter = count(0)

res = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(dates, key=lambda x: int(x.replace('-', '')) - next(counter))]

for g in res:
    print(g)
```

**Output**

```
['2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12']
['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11']
['2020-01']
['2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05']
['2020-09', '2020-10']
```

The above code listing is an adaptation of an old recipe for finding runs of consecutive numbers, see the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#examples)

The main idea is to group the input by the *key* function, to better understand what it's happening let's apply the *key* function to the values:

```
res = list(map(lambda x: int(x.replace('-', '')) - next(counter), dates))
print(res)
```

**Output** *(mapping key to the elements of dates)*

```
[201707, 201707, 201707, 201707, 201707, 201707, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201895, 201984, 201985, 201985, 201985, 201988, 201988]
```

As it can be seen the consecutive run of months are all mapped to the same key, to understand why this happens check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list).

As as side note, we need to do *list(group)* because group is an iterable not a *list*.

Comment: @dani im interested in understanding the nested loop, is there a way to explain it a bit ^_^?