# Dataframe: find the largest consecutive group of equal numbers in a dataframe and get the first and last index of this group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

**example Datafrmae:**

```
col1 = {"a" : [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, 4 , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=col1)
```

1. to find the largest group of consecutive NaN values from the dataframe.
2. To return the first and last index from the group

in this example the output would be: (7, 12)

Comment: you may want to have your data imported like this instead:
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(col1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` on null values to get the "streaks" of consecutive null/non-null values:

```
streaks = df["a"].isnull().groupby(df["a"].isnull().ne(df["a"].isnull().shift()).cumsum()).transform(sum)
indices = df[streaks==streaks.max()].index

>>> indices[0], indices[-1]
(7, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
# Fill NAN with some dummy value.
df.a = df.a.fillna(-999)
# Check if value is equal to last value, and add a value each time group changes:
df['groups'] = (df.a != df.a.shift()).cumsum()
# Count the size of each group and select the biggest:
biggest_group = df.groupby('groups').size().max()
# Query that group and fetch first and last index:
min_index, *_, max_index = df[df['groups'] == biggest_group].index
```

Answer (score 0):

We can filter the dataframe for `NaN` values and use the resulting index as the numerical sequence for this answer (slightly adapted): [identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list).

Example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

ranges = {}
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(df.loc[df['a'].isna()].index), lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
    seq = tuple(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    ranges[seq] = len(seq)
print(ranges)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2, 3): 3, (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12): 6}
```

The resulting `ranges` dictionary has a tuple of indices where the `NaN` values appeared in `df` as keys, and the length of each consecutive range as values.