# how to check and rearrange Python's list which contains a series of incremental values

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am just wondering how the list could be rearranged into list of list with a series of incremental integers as list element. For example, let's imagine that I have a list as follows:

```
example = [2, 43, 44, 64, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 211]
```

And I would like to convert this list into the one as follows:

```
converted_example = [[2], [43, 44], [64], [143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148], [178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184], [211]]
```

Do you have any ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools


def groupby_adjacent(max_step_size=1):
    # generate a persistent function that tracks successive calls, 
    # to feed to itertools.groupby
    # (assume the input is already sorted)
    v = {
        'last': None,   # last value encountered
        'group': 0      # value to return for groupby
    }
    def f(current):
        # if the current element exceeds the last element by more than one,
        # break the groupby and start a new group
        if v['last'] is not None and current - max_step_size > v['last']:
            v['group'] = v['group'] + 1
        # otherwise, just keep the same group as we currently have
        v['last'] = current
        return v['group']
    return f

example = [2, 43, 44, 64, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 211]

converted_example = [list(tup[1]) for tup in 
                         itertools.groupby(sorted(example), key=groupby_adjacent())
                    ]
# [[2], [43, 44], [64], [143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148], [178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184], [211]]
```

Each call of `groupby_adjacent()` will produce a new version of `f` with its own set of unique local variables, and the returned `f` can then be passed to a single `.groupby()` function. I used a dict to store variables instead of actually using variables because I wanted to avoid using the `global` keyword (it can have behavior reaching beyond where you might intend it to).

The call to `sorted()` can, of course, be omitted if you can guarantee that `example` will already be sorted.

Comment: How about `nonlocal`?