# How to find the first number of multiple consecutive sequence in list

Tags: python, list

I use input
[0,2,3,4,6,7,8,16,17,18,21,23,24,26,34,35,36,37,38,40,41,46,47]

But output
[0,2,6,16,21,23,26,34,40,46] which is wrong
Should be [2,6,16,23,34,40,46]

How to find the first number of multiple consecutive sequence in list?

If it is possible, can be editable to find the last one too
Such that [4, 8, 18, 24, 38, 41, 47]

```
def find_consecutive_numbers(lst):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst)-2:
        if lst[i]+1 == lst[i+1] and lst[i+1]+1 == lst[i+2]:
            result.append(lst[i])
            i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    return result
```

I had tried to ask chatgpt, but result is not perfect.
It use string to do first.
But some unexpected numbers in list too

Comment: *"But output [0,2,6,16,21,23,26,34,40,46]..."*: that's not the output of the code you shared.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-consecutive-numbers-in-a-list

Comment: You can ask chatgpt to write code, then you can know it has some numbers unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping by difference to preceding element and yield the first of each group that difference is `1`:

```
from itertools import pairwise, groupby

def find_consecutive_numbers(lst, last=False):
    for k, g in groupby(pairwise(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0]):
        if k == 1:
            if last:
                *_, (_, end) = g
                yield end
            else:
                yield next(g)[0]

>>> list(find_consecutive_numbers(l))
[2, 6, 16, 23, 34, 40, 46]
>>> list(find_consecutive_numbers(l, last=True))
[4, 8, 18, 24, 38, 41, 47]
```

Some docs:

- [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)
- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- [Generator functions (`yield`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)
- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: This is better than chatgpt. However, need to install new python 3.11 in order to use pairwise. Syntax is quite advanced.

Comment: @Maiva - ```pairwise``` comes in Python 3.10.  And if you don't want to upgrade, you can still write your *own* version too.

Comment: @Maiva `pairwise = lambda lst: zip(lst, lst[1:])` for older versions (you could use `itertools.islice` instead of the more spatious list slice).