# Group list by values

Tags: python, list, grouping

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
mylist = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]
```

How can I most elegantly group this to get this list output in Python:

```
[["A", "C"], ["B"], ["D", "E"]]
```

So the values are grouped by the secound value but the order is preserved...

Comment: `list` is a data type in Python, it is not recommended to use it as a variable name

Comment: I edited the question so it doesn't shadow the built-in `list` keyword

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
values = set(map(lambda x:x[1], mylist))
newlist = [[y[0] for y in mylist if y[1]==x] for x in values]
```

Comment: `set()` isn't necessarily sorted (though it is for small integer values), if you have a long range use `values = sorted(set(...`

Comment: @sverre after all it was not required to be sorted

Comment: Except that `set` does not have an order. It just so happens that for low integers the hash function is identity. I'm also uncertain whether OP intended both orders (order of groups and order in groups) or not; this and sverre's examples sort the groups by key (his also assumes 0..N continuous range).

Comment: `lambda x:x[1]` could be replaced with [`operator.itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Thanks for this. Just FYI to those coming across this, instead of the `map`, it's more Pythonic to use a comprehension: `values = set(x for x in list if x[1])`

Comment: I edited this answer, like the question, so it doesn't shadow the built-in `list` keyword

Comment: The group could be simply done in `O(n)`, but in this block of code, if elements in `mylist` are all distinct, it would cost `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: agree with @yuanzhendai

Comment: I completely agree with @yuanzhendai, you should at least specify that the complexity is far from optimal

Answer (score 45):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

lki = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]
lki.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

glo = [[x for x,y in g]
       for k,g in  groupby(lki,key=itemgetter(1))]

print glo
```

.

EDIT

Another solution that needs no import , is more readable, keeps the orders, and is 22 % shorter than the preceding one:

```
oldlist = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]

newlist, dicpos = [],{}
for val,k in oldlist:
    if k in dicpos:
        newlist[dicpos[k]].extend(val)
    else:
        newlist.append([val])
        dicpos[k] = len(dicpos)

print newlist
```

Comment: +1 for using `itemgetter`.  But note that since you're iterating over the iterators returned by `groupby`, you don't need `list(g)`.

Comment: @Robert Rossney Eagle's eye. +1 . By the way, in your code, I find the word 'data' too common to give an idea of what sort of data it is, that's a pity.

Answer (score 31):

Howard's answer is concise and elegant, but it's also O(n^2) in the worst case. For large lists with large numbers of grouping key values, you'll want to sort the list first and then use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> seq = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]
>>> seq.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
>>> groups = groupby(seq, itemgetter(1))
>>> [[item[0] for item in data] for (key, data) in groups]
[['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['D', 'E']]
```

**Edit:**

I changed this after seeing eyequem's answer:  `itemgetter(1)` is nicer than `lambda x: x[1]`.

Comment: But it needs an import. Is it really better than using a lambda ? I wonder. Anyway, for readibility, itemgetter is better, I think

Comment: I think so too.  Also, it's always good to be reminded of the existence of the `operator` module.

Comment: I like lambda better.

Comment: I think lambda is much better. Its always good not needed to be reminded of a rare module!

Comment: I also like the lambda better, but I think number of imports is not an important consideration, because operator module is part of the standard library. Dependencies are bad, imports are not.

Answer (score 16):

```
>>> import collections
>>> D1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for element in L1:
...     D1[element[1]].append(element[0])
... 
>>> L2 = D1.values()
>>> print L2
[['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['D', 'E']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about elegant, but it's certainly doable:

```
oldlist = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]
# change into: list = [["A", "C"], ["B"], ["D", "E"]]

order=[]
dic=dict()
for value,key in oldlist:
  try:
    dic[key].append(value)
  except KeyError:
    order.append(key)
    dic[key]=[value]
newlist=map(dic.get, order)

print newlist
```

This preserves the order of the first occurence of each key, as well as the order of items for each key. It requires the key to be hashable, but does not otherwise assign meaning to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
len = max(key for (item, key) in list)
newlist = [[] for i in range(len+1)]
for item,key in list:
  newlist[key].append(item)
```

You can do it in a single list comprehension, perhaps more elegant but O(n**2):

```
[[item for (item,key) in list if key==i] for i in range(max(key for (item,key) in list)+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> xs = [["A",0], ["B",1], ["C",0], ["D",2], ["E",2]]
>>> xs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> reduce(lambda l, x: (l.append([x]) if l[-1][0][1] != x[1] else l[-1].append(x)) or l, xs[1:], [[xs[0]]]) if xs else []
[[['A', 0], ['C', 0]], [['B', 1]], [['D', 2], ['E', 2]]]
```

Basically, if the list is sorted, it is possible to `reduce` by looking at the last group constructed by the previous steps - you can tell if you need to start a new group, or modify an existing group. The `... or l` bit is a trick that enables us to use `lambda` in Python. (`append` returns `None`. It is always better to return something more useful than `None`, but, alas, such is Python.)

Answer (score 1):

if using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which provides a lot of data processing primitives and generates ad hoc code under the hood, then:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

my_list = [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 0], ["D", 2], ["E", 2]]

# store the converter somewhere because this is where code generation
# takes place
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(1))
    .aggregate(c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item(0)))
    .gen_converter()
)
assert converter(my_list) == [["A", "C"], ["B"], ["D", "E"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer inspired by @Howard's answer.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def group_by(nested_iterables: Iterable[Iterable], key_index: int) \
    -> List[Tuple[Any, Iterable[Any]]]:
    """ Groups elements nested in <nested_iterables> based on their <key_index>_th element.

    Behaves similarly to itertools.groupby when the input to the itertools function is sorted.

    E.g. If <nested_iterables> = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 2), (9, 3)] and 
    <key_index> = 1, we will return [(2, [(1, 2), (5, 2)]), (3, [(2, 3), (9,3)])].

    Returns:
        A list of (group_key, values) tuples where <values> is an iterator of the iterables in
            <nested_iterables> that all have their <key_index>_th element equal to <group_key>.
    """
    group_keys = set(map(itemgetter(key_index), nested_iterables))
    return [(key, list(filter(lambda x: x[key_index] == key, nested_iterables)))
             for key in group_keys]
```