# How to divide a list into a list of smaller lists based on a predicate?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
[('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
```

And I'd like to convert it to a list like this:

```
[ [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)], [('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)] ]
```

Assuming the list is sorted wrt the predicate on which it should be split -

What's the Pythonic way of doing this?

Is there any function that does this or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: checkout similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695208/group-list-by-values

Answer (score 8):

You can use `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]

l.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])

result = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(l, key=lambda item: item[0])]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the list comprehension is only necessary if you want it as a list. `groupby` on its own returns an iterator, so if all you're doing is iterating, that's good enough.

Comment: Or `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, `operator.itemgetter` is okay. I think use lambda function is more easy to understand the key is a one parameter function.

Comment: groupby group only the adjacent elements! This results in wrong output for input like `[('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4), ('Yadda', 5)]`

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Yes, After test the list you gave. We should sort before `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

Groupby of itertools groups the adjacent elements.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
>>> print [list(group) for _, group in groupby(l, key=lambda item: item[0])]
[[('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)], [('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]]
>>>
>>> #if the list is not sorted!     
>>> l2 = [('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4), ('Yadda', 5)]
>>> print [list(group) for _, group in groupby(l2, key=lambda item: item[0])]
[[('Yadda', 9)], [('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)], [('Yadda', 5)]]
```

- Its important to sort the list before you proceed!

So after sorting,

```
>>> l2 = [('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4), ('Yadda', 5)]
>>> get_first=key=lambda item: item[0]
>>> print [list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(l2,key=get_first), get_first)]
[[('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)], [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)]]
```

- You can also use filter!

As,

```
>>> l=[('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
>>> s=set(map(lambda item: item[0],l))
>>> print [filter(lambda x:name in x,l) for name in s]
[[('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)], [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)]]
```

- You can also use itemgetter,

That is,

```
>>> l=[('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s=set(map(itemgetter(0),l))
>>> print [filter(lambda x:name in x,l) for name in s]
[[('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)], [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are splitting the list based on the first item of the inner list, I would use a dictionary.

```
l = [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
d={}
for x in l:
  if x[0] not in d:
    d[x[0]]=[x]
  else:
    d[x[0]].append(x)
print(d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way.

```
list = [('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4), ('Yadda', 5)]
ls_set = (set([ls[0] for ls in list]))
ls_dict = {}
for ls in ls_set:
    ls_dict[ls] = []
for ls in list:
    ls_dict[ls[0]].append(ls[1])
final_list = []
for key, value in ls_dict.items():
    a = []
    for i in value:
        a.append(tuple([key,i]))
    final_list.append(a)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want without any package or `itertools` then this will help you,

```
>>> l = [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9), ('Blah', 12), ('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4)]
>>> l.sort(key= lambda x:x[1])
>>> values = set(map(lambda x:x[0], l))
>>> [[y for y in l if y[0]==i] for i in values]
[[('Blah', 2), ('Blah', 4), ('Blah', 12)], [('Yadda', 5), ('Yadda', 9)]]
>>>
```