# How to group dicts (compare dicts) based on all the keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I'm writing a python script which parses "n" number of xml's first and creates a dict of dict's with key-value being xml attributes (inside nested dicts).
Now, I want to group these nested dicts stored to know which xml's are same and can be grouped into same group.
I want some pythonic way to group the same dict's where each dict happens to have same keys.

- I tried with parsing each dict and creating a string from the values.
  Store this string inside a dict where key = string and value = list of xmlNames. Now, when I go to the next dict and form the string, if it already exists in the dict, then I simply append the xml to this dict's value.
- I think there can be a better method based on groupby() or something else.

```py
list_of_xmls =  ["a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml", "d.xml"]
dictXml = dict()
for xml in list_of_xmls:
    dictXml[xml] = parseXml(xml)   # Returns dict by parsing xml (key-value)

# parseXml(xml)
# It parses xml and returns dict like:
dict for a.xml = {"config":"4", "location":"C:\\xyz", "Group":"amcat"}
dict for b.xml = {"config":"4", "location":"C:\\xyz", "Group":"amcat"}
dict for c.xml = {"config":"5", "location":"C:\\mno", "Group":"alien"}
dict for d.xml = {"config":"5", "location":"C:\\mno", "Group":"alien"}

# Supoose, a.xml and b.xml have same values for all keys
# Same for c.xml and d.xml
# So, I should have two groups (a.xml, b.xml) and (c.xml, d.xml)
 ###########Some processing on the above dict ######

finalOutput = [["a.xml", "b.xml], ["c.xml", "d.xml"]]
```

Output should be list of groups which can be clubbed (basically list of lists).

Also, dictXml can be any other data structure as well like list of dicts.
Any thoughts ?

Basically, the whole idea is given a list of xml's, I need to figure out which xml's are same based on key-values inside it. Group the same xml's in some list and do processing on each group.

Comment: How does `parseXml` look like?

Comment: It works on some schema internally.
However, it finally returns a dict with key and value after processing xml.
Don't have any other details of it.
Also, parseXML can't be changed.

Comment: and how does that dict look like? and what's the final desired output? a visual exmaple will be appreciated

Comment: Thanks Devesh for looking.
Updated parseXml in the code.
Hope that helps.

Comment: and how do you want the final output to look like?

Comment: Updated desired output.
Thanks

Comment: Basically, the whole idea is given a list of xml's,
I need to figure out which xml's are same based on key-values inside it.
Group the same xml's in some list and do processing on each group.

Comment: also when you say same values for all keys, what does it mean, can you also add how will the output of parseXml would look for all 4 xml ?

Comment: Sorry.
Added that too.
Now, it should be fine.

Comment: c.xml and d.xml are different though `"location":"C:\\mo"` vs `"location":"C:\\mno" ?

Comment: missed 'n' :(
done

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby))  to do the grouping:

```
list_of_xmls =  ["a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml", "d.xml"]

dictXml = {
'a.xml': {"config":"4", "location":"C:\\xyz", "Group":"amcat"},
'c.xml': {"config":"5", "location":"C:\\mno", "Group":"alien"},
'b.xml': {"config":"4", "location":"C:\\xyz", "Group":"amcat"},
'd.xml': {"config":"5", "location":"C:\\mno", "Group":"alien"},
}

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

out = []
f = itemgetter(1)
s = sorted([(k, [i for i in v.items()]) for k, v in dictXml.items()], key=f)
for _, g in groupby(s, f):
    out.append([i[0] for i in g])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['a.xml', 'b.xml'], ['c.xml', 'd.xml']]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Can you please answer it for python 2.7 or below ?
It says : Python version <3.5 doesn't support starred expression in tuple, list and sets.

Comment: @PeXXeR Updated my answer, tested it with Python 2.7.15

Comment: Thanks a lot for quickly helping here.
May I request you one more thing.
I could barely understand what is going on here.
Can you please explain briefly ?
I am asking this to figure out is there a better way in terms of time complexity after analyzing this or yours might be the best way.

Comment: @PeXXeR The complexity is O(n logn) because of the `sorted()` function. First we sort `dictXml` by list we create from `dictXml.values`. Then we apply `itertools.groupby` on this sorted list and extract the keys from each group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first I get only the xml name and the group it is in into a list of tuples then applied this grouping algorithm [Group list by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695208/group-list-by-values)

```
dictXml = {"a.xml":{"Group":"a"}, "b.xml":{"Group":"b"}, "c.xml":{"Group":"b"}, "d.xml":{"Group":"d"}}

xml_group_list = [(xml, xml_dic["Group"]) for xml, xml_dic in dictXml.items()]
values = set(map(lambda x: x[1], xml_group_list))
newlist = [[y[0] for y in xml_group_list if y[1] == x] for x in values]
print(newlist)
```

output:

```
[['a.xml'], ['b.xml', 'c.xml'], ['d.xml']]
```

Comment: Thanks.
I am not a python expert.
But, the xml happens to have around 70 keys.
So, how to use the code in that case ?
can you please help.

Comment: replace `a` with `dictXml`

Comment: also remove the first line that was just a sample example. start from `xml_group_list... `

Answer (score 0):

I have another method to solve your problem.
As I do't know parseXML(), so decided to take predefine_dict. hope you understand.
you can replace predefined_dict[xml] with parseXML(xml)

```
list_of_xmls =  ["a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml", "d.xml"]
predefined_dict = {"a.xml":{"name":"mice", "surename":"dine"},
                     "b.xml":{"name":"akks", "surename":"john"}, 
                     "c.xml":{"name":"mice", "surename":"dine"},
                     "d.xml":{"name":"akks", "surename":"john"}}
dictXml = dict()
finalOutput =[]
temp_dict={}
for xml in list_of_xmls:
    temp = tuple([i for i in predefined_dict[xml].values()])
    print(temp)
    try:
        dictXml[temp].append(xml)
    except KeyError:
        dictXml[temp]= [xml]

print(dictXml)
for value in dictXml.values():
    finalOutput.append(value)
print("finalOutput", finalOutput)
```