# Python: How do I split a list into multiple by comparing its contents?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an list such as:

```
list = [[1, 3, 'orange'], [3, 5, 'apple'], [2, 3, 'orange'], [7, 9, 'pear']]
```

and i would like to convert it into multiple lists such as:

```
list1 = [[1, 3, 'orange'], [2, 3, 'orange']]
list2 = [3, 5, 'apple']
list3 = [7, 9, 'pear']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried yet? Can you show us the code to help you? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Could you make the “rule” explicit? How should the algorithm decide which elements to put in which list?

Comment: They should be in the same order as the original list, but separated by the value in the third column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group list by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695208/group-list-by-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can iterate over list.
2. Now check if your filter element is present inside list.

```
for l in list:
    if filter_element in l:
        filtered_list1.append(l)
    elif condition2:
        filtered_list2.append(l)
```

If you want to do this more aesthetically use can use filter from functools.