# How to count consecutive identical numbers and do some calculations in a Python list

Tags: python, list, replace, count

I have a list that looks like this.

[6, **1, 1, 1**, 5, **1**, 7, **1**, 7, **1**, 7, 7, 7, **1**, 7, **1, 1**, 3, **1, 1, 1, 1**]

There are some consecutive 1s in it.

After counting the number of consecutive 1s, I want to sum all the 1s and add 1 to each sum like this.

1,1,1,1 => 5
1,1,1 => 4
1,1 => 3 
1 => 2

And then, I want to put them in each place where the consecutive 1 were.

[6,  **4**,  5, **2**, 7, **2**, 7, **2**, 7, 7, 7, **2**, 3, **5**]

Finally, I want to change any numbers other than 1 to 1 without changing the bold text.

[1, **4**, 1, **2**, 1, **2**, 1, **2**, 1, 1, 1, **2**, 1, **5**]

How can I do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't ask for much, do you? It sure would be great to see what you actually tried, given that "help" implies effort from both sides and you have given _none_

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we [cannot offer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) "help", and [do not care about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) "appreciation". We *do* want questions that are clear, specific and *focused* - i.e., which are **one** question at a time. If you can group up the consecutive identical numbers, the rest should follow naturally. If it doesn't, then you have separate questions about the rest of the logical steps.

Comment: If being able to make the groups easily is enough information, then that is already a common duplicate: please refer to [How do I use itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/) or [Group list by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695208).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]

res = []
for k,g in groupby(lst):
    if k==1:
        res.append(len(list(g))+1)
    else:
        res.extend([1]*len(list(g)))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> x = [6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> new_x = []
>>> for i,g in groupby(x):
        if i==1:
            new_x.append(1+sum(g))
        else:
            new_x += [1 for _ in g]

        
>>> new_x
[1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5]
```