# Filter Anagram in Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, anagram

I'm trying to go through an array and delete the elements that aren't anagrams in python.  Here is the code I wrote.  My logic seems fine but I can't seem to get it.

```
b = ['cat', 'dog', 'god', 'star', 'lap', 'act']
array=[]
t=0
for i in b:
    while t<len(b):
        if ''.join(sorted(i))==''.join(sorted(b[t])):
           array.append(i)
        t+=1
print array
```

Comment: You mean all elements in the array should be anagrams in your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some minor tweaks to your existing code should work.

```
b = ['cat', 'dog', 'god', 'star', 'lap', 'act']
array = []
t = 0
for i, value in enumerate(b):
    t = i+1
    while t<len(b):
        if ''.join(sorted(value))==''.join(sorted(b[t])):
            array.extend([value, b[t]])
        t+=1
print array
['cat', 'act', 'dog', 'god']
```

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU! and it makes a lot of sense;

Answer (score 0):

First issue in your program, is that you are initializing `t` to `0` outside the for loop , hence you you only check the first element of `b` with all the elements, for the rest of the iterations of the `for` loop , t would always be greater than len(b) , hence it never goes inside the inner loop, from second iteration of `for` loop. A simple fix -

```
for i in b:
    t = 0
    while t<len(b):
        if ''.join(sorted(i))==''.join(sorted(b[t])):
           array.append(i)
        t+=1
```

---

But for finding anagrams, i think you are over-complicating it, you can simple find out sum of ASCII values of the characters of the string, and then compare it with other same sums and lengths , and check if both sum of ASCII value and length of string match, if they do they are anagram.

Example code for this method -

```
b = ['cat', 'dog', 'god', 'star', 'lap', 'act']
c = list(map(len,b))
d = list(map(lambda x: sum([ord(c) for c in x]), b))
arr= []
for i, s in enumerate(b):
    for j, s1 in enumerate(b):
            if d[i] == d[j] and c[i] == c[j] and i != j:
                    if s not in arr:
                            arr.append(s)
                    if s1 not in arr:
                            arr.append(s1)
print(arr)
>> ['cat', 'act', 'dog', 'god']
```

Comment: Welcome. Also, please do remember to accept any answer that has solved your problem. Would help the community a lot

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach

Using itertools groupby

```
In [18]: from itertools import groupby


In [19]: c=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(b,key=sorted),sorted)]

In [20]: c
Out[20]: [['cat', 'act'], ['lap'], ['star'], ['dog', 'god']]

In [21]: [x for _list in c if len(_list)>1 for x in _list]
Out[21]: ['cat', 'act', 'dog', 'god']
```

> The key thing here is to use itertools.groupby from the itertools
>   module which will group items in a list together.
>
> The list we supply to groupby has to be sorted in advanced so we pass
>   it sorted(b,key=sorted). The trick here is that sorted can take a
>   key function and will sort based on the output from this function, so
>   we pass sorted again as the key function and this will will sort the
>   words using the letters of the string in order. There's no need to
>   define our own function or create a lambda.
>
> groupby takes a key function which it uses to tell if items should be
>   grouped together and again we can just pass it the built-in sorted
>   function.

Source:[Finding and grouping anagrams by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181513/finding-and-grouping-anagrams-by-python)

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a library for practice purposes; Regardless, I'll have to learn it anyways and I appreciate your explanation and help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually your solution is wrong and the idea of using 2 `for` loop is not efficient. you are iterating over your list 2 time and apply `''.join(sorted())` 2 time on your elements also you are comparing each element with itself! instead that you can use a dictionary to get the indices of the anagram elements with iterating over the `enumerate` of your list :

```
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in enumerate(b):
...   d.setdefault(''.join(sorted(j)),[]).append(i)
... 
>>> d
{'arst': [3], 'dgo': [1, 2], 'alp': [4], 'act': [0, 5]}

>>> [b[t] for k in d.values() if len(k)>1 for t in k]
['dog', 'god', 'cat', 'act']
```

And if you care about the order you can use `OrderedDict` function from `collections` module :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for i,j in enumerate(b):
...   d.setdefault(''.join(sorted(j)),[]).append(i)
... 
>>> [b[t] for k in d.values() if len(k)>1 for t in k]
['cat', 'act', 'dog', 'god']
```

Comment: Thank you! Although it isn't what I was looking for, I did learn a lot from your response.