# how to sort out repeated entry from a column in python

Tags: python

i have a file like:

```
q12j4
q12j4
fj45j
q12j4
fjmep
fj45j
```

now all i wanted to do is:

- find if any entries are repeated,
- if so then print the entry once and those are not repeated print 'em normally.
  the output should be like:

  ```
  q12j4  
  fj45j  
  fjmep
  ```

  [repetition is omitted]

I was trying to do it with `defaultdict`function but I think it will not work for strings.
please help..

Comment: wouldn't unix' `uniq` do the job better than python?

Comment: only if order isn't important and you can sort it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seen = set()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line not in seen:
            print line
            seen.add(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    for val in seq:
        if val not in seen:
            seen.add(val)
            yield val

with open('file.txt') as f:
    print ''.join(unique(f))
```

As you can see, I've chosen to write a separate generator for removing duplicates from an iterable. This generator, `unique()`, can be used in lots of other contexts too.

Comment: @sehe: If you're subtly referring to your own answer, that answer doesn't produce the result that the OP is asking for. Besides, we are not playing code golf here.

Comment: @sehe I thought you were referring to `[x for x in L if x not in s and not s.add(x)]` but this code is more readable imo.

Comment: @jamylak: That is very interesting, but I don't play codegolf :) I just meant like [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601038/85371). Readability first. Optimize --later-- never.

Answer (score 3):

This should be roughly enough:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in set(f):
        print line
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the order of entries.

Comment: @aix - The OP does not explicitly mention preservation of order as one of his requirements. His question does mention `sort out` but that can easily be interpreted as `take out`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the itertools.groupby function, for an example of usage, look at the standard library or this related question: [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)

Assume that `toorder` is your list with repeated entries:

```
import itertools
toorder = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(toorder)):
    print key
```

Should output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Even assuming order isn't important, this is massive overkill for just eliminating duplicates.

Comment: That's true, but I pointed this out for the versatility and readablity of groupby, in respect to an "ad hoc" solution.