# Find indices of N concurrences in arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array that I obtain from using `sp.distance.cdist`, and such array looks as follows:

```
 [ 0.          5.37060126  2.68530063  4.65107712  2.68530063  4.65107712
   2.04846297  7.41906423  4.11190697  6.50622284  4.11190697  6.50622284]
 [ 5.37060126  0.          4.65107712  2.68530063  4.65107712  2.68530063
   7.41906423  2.04846297  6.50622284  4.11190697  6.50622284  4.11190697]
 [ 2.68530063  4.65107712  0.          2.68530063  4.65107712  5.37060126
   4.11190697  6.50622284  2.04846297  4.11190697  6.50622284  7.41906423]
 [ 4.65107712  2.68530063  2.68530063  0.          5.37060126  4.65107712
   6.50622284  4.11190697  4.11190697  2.04846297  7.41906423  6.50622284]
 [ 2.68530063  4.65107712  4.65107712  5.37060126  0.          2.68530063
   4.11190697  6.50622284  6.50622284  7.41906423  2.04846297  4.11190697]
 [ 4.65107712  2.68530063  5.37060126  4.65107712  2.68530063  0.
   6.50622284  4.11190697  7.41906423  6.50622284  4.11190697  2.04846297]
 [ 2.04846297  7.41906423  4.11190697  6.50622284  4.11190697  6.50622284
   0.          9.4675272   4.7337636   8.19911907  4.7337636   8.19911907]
 [ 7.41906423  2.04846297  6.50622284  4.11190697  6.50622284  4.11190697
   9.4675272   0.          8.19911907  4.7337636   8.19911907  4.7337636 ]
 [ 4.11190697  6.50622284  2.04846297  4.11190697  6.50622284  7.41906423
   4.7337636   8.19911907  0.          4.7337636   8.19911907  9.4675272 ]
 [ 6.50622284  4.11190697  4.11190697  2.04846297  7.41906423  6.50622284
   8.19911907  4.7337636   4.7337636   0.          9.4675272   8.19911907]
 [ 4.11190697  6.50622284  6.50622284  7.41906423  2.04846297  4.11190697
   4.7337636   8.19911907  8.19911907  9.4675272   0.          4.7337636 ]
 [ 6.50622284  4.11190697  7.41906423  6.50622284  4.11190697  2.04846297
   8.19911907  4.7337636   9.4675272   8.19911907  4.7337636   0.        ]]
```

What I'm trying to do, using numpy, is to search some values, for example between `2.7` and `2.3`, and at the same time I'd also like to return the indices when they are found in the rows of the arrays. I have read a lot, and I have found for example `.argmin()`, which does partially what I want (but it only shows you where the zeros or values lower than zero are located, and just one concurrence). In the documentation of [.argmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) I cannot find anything related on how find the minimum different from zero and that it doesn't stop after the first concurrence. I need to do it for these values in the interval. To explain myself better, this is what I expect to get:

e.g.:

```
[row (0), index (2), index (4)]
[row (1), index (3), index (5)]
[row (2), index (0), index (3)]
```

What would be the best way to do this? In the meantime, I'll keep trying and if I find a solution I'll post it here.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to use the array indices for? You are probably better of simply using the result of `(v > 2.3) & (v < 2.7)` (a boolean array) instead of an array of indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you looking for is the `np.argwhere` function, which tells you index-wise where a condition in an array is satisfied.

```
v = np.array([[ 0.     ,     5.37060126,  2.68530063 , 4.65107712 , 2.5 ],
              [ 5.37060126 ,  4.65107712 , 2.68530063 ,.11190697,1 ]])


np.argwhere((v > 2.3) & (v < 2.7))

array([[0, 2],
        [0, 4],
         [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `numpy.where`, which returns a tuple containing the indices of each dimension where some condition is `True` for the values of an `numpy.ndarray`. Example using your data:

```
i, j = np.where(((a > 2.3) & (a < 2.7)))
#(array([ 0,  0,  2,  2,  4,  4,  6,  6,  8,  8, 10, 10], dtype=int64),
# array([2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 1, 4], dtype=int64))
```

Then you can use `groupby` to put the output in the format that you want:

```
from itertools import groupby
for k,g in itertools.groupby(zip(i, j), lambda x: x[0]):
    print k, [tmp[1] for tmp in zip(*g)]
#0 [0, 4]
#2 [2, 5]
#4 [4, 3]
#6 [6, 2]
#8 [8, 5]
#10 [10, 4]
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution, but I always get errors. I was also reading on [how to use groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) but nothing so far.


`for k,g in groupby(zip(i,j), lambda x: x[0]):`
`NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

Comment: @muammar `i, j` are the indices returned by `np.where`... I forgot to put in the answer... now I've edited it and it should work!

Comment: Both `argwhere` and `where` use `nonzero`.