# multi variable for loops python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to understand what is happening in this piece of code. I can see what it does, but the process for how it gets there eludes me.

```
from itertools import groupby
lines = '''
This is the
first paragraph.

This is the second.
'''.splitlines()
# Use itertools.groupby and bool to return groups of
# consecutive lines that either have content or don't.
for has_chars, frags in groupby(lines, bool):
    if has_chars:
        print ' '.join(frags)
# PRINTS:
# This is the first paragraph.
# This is the second.
```

I think my confusion surrounds the multiple variables in the for loop (in this instance `has_chars` and `frags`). How are multiple variables possible? What is happening? How is python dealing with multiple variables? What am I saying to python when I put multiple variables in a for loop? Is there a limit to how many variables you can create in a for loop? How can I ask a precise question when I don't understand enough about programming to actually form one?

I've tried running it through the python visualiser to get a better understanding. That thing has never made anything clearer for me. Try as I oft do.

Comment: This post is pretty helpful in understanding how groupby works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby

Comment: See here: https://github.com/pas-campitiello/python/blob/master/2-NotesSimplePrograms.md#15-lines-itertools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [python-course](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_for_loop.php)

> As we mentioned earlier, the Python for loop is an iterator based for
>   loop. It steps through the items in any ordered sequence list, i.e.
>   string, lists, tuples, the keys of dictionaries and other iterables.
>   The Python for loop starts with the keyword "for" followed by an
>   arbitrary variable name, which will hold the **values** of the following
>   sequence object, which is stepped through. The general syntax looks
>   like this:

```
for <variable> in <sequence>:
    <statements>
else:
    <statements>
```

Let say you have list of tuples like

```
In [37]: list1 = [('a', 'b', 123, 'c'), ('d', 'e', 234, 'f'), ('g', 'h', 345, 'i')]
```

You can iterate over it as,

```
In [38]: for i in list1:
   ....:     print i
   ....:     
('a', 'b', 123, 'c')
('d', 'e', 234, 'f')
('g', 'h', 345, 'i')

In [39]: for i,j,k,l in list1:
    print i,',', j,',',k,',',l
   ....:     
a , b , 123 , c
d , e , 234 , f
g , h , 345 , i
```

> > > for k, v in os.environ.items():
> > >       ...     print "%s=%s" % (k, v)

```
USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\mpilgrim
OS=Windows_NT
COMPUTERNAME=MPILGRIM
USERNAME=mpilgrim
```

You can read about tuple unpacking as mentioned by @iCodez.  at [Tuples in Python](http://developingable.com/tuples-in-python/) and [Unpacking Tuples](http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/630101/Learn-to-Program-using-Python-Unpacking-Tuples.htm) links, they explained it with proper examples.

Comment: I now know that what I needed to be searching for was tuple unpacking or something to that effect.