# Python - groupby of multiple elements (tuple list)

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested, tuples

I have the following list of tuples: `[('platform','train','time')]`

```
travel= [(2,5,'09-19-2014'),(2,3,'07-19-2014'),(1,5,'06-19-2014'),(2,3,'04-19-2014').(1,5,'01-19-2014'),(1,2,'02-19-2014')]
```

I would like my output to be like this:

```
Platform 1: train 2: 02-19-2014, train 5: 02-19-2014, 06-19-2014
Platform 2: train 3: 04-19-2014, 07-19-2014 train 5: 09-19-2014
```

So far I only got:

```
Platform 1: train 2, train 5
Platform 2: train 3, train 5
```

Using this code:

```
        for key, group in groupby(travel, lambda x: x[0]):
            listOfThings = " , ".join(["%s" % thing[1] for thing in group])
            print "Platform " + key + ": " + listOfThings
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) post!

How will I have to change the code in order to get the desired output?

Comment: Either sort the list by platform number first or use a dictionary with platform number as key.

Answer (score 5):

`groupby` requires that the iterable passed to it is sorted which the below code does. The first `groupby` groups by platform. Then a second `groupby` is used to group the times by train.

```
from itertools import groupby

travel= [(2,5,'09-19-2014'),(2,3,'07-19-2014'),(1,5,'06-19-2014'),(2,3,'04-19-2014'),(1,5,'01-19-2014'),(1,2,'02-19-2014')]

for platform, g1 in groupby(sorted(travel), lambda t: t[0]):
    print 'Platform {}: '.format(platform),
    trains = []
    for train, times in groupby(sorted(g1), lambda t: t[1]):
        trains.append('train {}: {}'.format(train, ', '.join(time[2] for time in times)))
    print ', '.join(trains)
```

**Output**

```
Platform 1:  train 2: 02-19-2014, train 5: 01-19-2014, 06-19-2014
Platform 2:  train 3: 04-19-2014, 07-19-2014, train 5: 09-19-2014
```

Comment: @Sepi Then why don't you accept it as the correct answer :)