# Group By operation for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a simple way/module to do a group-by operation in python for datasets too large to fit in the memory?

I would usually use pandas, but it breaks down for large datasets.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) might help.

Comment: Maybe you can use sqlite3.exe to aggregate data out-of-the-core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment, @steboc mentioned using sqlite as a possible solution. You could use any database as a backend for this, but sqlite is reasonably fast and requires almost zero set up. Here's an example of writing a bunch of junk to sqlite then reading it back in groups:

Start with loading a few packages and setting up the environment:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import string


## connect to a db. This db will be created if it does not exist
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

np.random.seed(123)
## create some random data in a pandas dataframe
n = 1000000
c = 10
```

Let's loop through 30 times and each time we'll create a dataframe with 1mm records, 10 numeric fields and a key that's simply a letter. We'll poke that dataframe in the sqlite database. At the end of the loop we'll have 30mm rows in our database. This takes ~15 minutes on my MBP:

```
%%time
for i in arange(30):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n, c), columns=list(map(chr, range(65, 65+c))))
    df['key'] = string.ascii_letters[i]
    df.to_sql(name='test_table', if_exists='append', con=conn)
```

Now if we were going to do an operation on all this data grouping by the values in the field `key` we'd first need to get all the unique values for the key. One way is to do this:

```
%%time
keys_df = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT DISTINCT key FROM test_table', con=conn)
keys_df
```

Now we have `keys_df` which is a dataframe with one column containing all the unique values for `key'. Now we can iterate through each group and extract only that group from the database and do our grouped operation. The example here does a trivial describe():

```
%%time
for row in keys_df.iterrows():
    tempdf = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE key=\'' + row[1][0] + '\';', con=conn)
    ## do anything you want with your group here. 
    ## we'll print describe just for fun
    print tempdf.describe()
    print ""
```

Obviously in real life you'd put the values in a data structure.

I hope this helps illustrate how to use sqlite and pandas to iterate over groups of data.

Answer (score 3):

The Blaze project is happy to manage large datasets by chunking the dataset and then using Pandas on each chunk.  The [Blaze out-of-core docs](http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/dev/ooc.html) might interest you.  And here is an [explicit example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/blaze.pydata.org/notebooks/timings-csv.ipynb) on the NYC Taxi dataset.

If you prefer a slower, pure-python solution then the `toolz` project might interest you.  Here are its documents on [streaming analytics](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/streaming-analytics.html)

Comment: Good example of why link-only answers are deprecated. only 1 out of three of those links persists at 18 months interval. Perhaps: http://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html