# Parsing a json and grouping contents

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a URL which gives a JSON result. I can parse the json and print the data from the JSON. But my main intention is to group each content and print them into an Excel sheet.

The code I wrote is:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = urllib2.urlopen("urlquery")
data = json.load(url)
print data
```

The data is printed in the `dict` type. Here each content has at least 10 parameters like `ID`, `Name`, `Rating`, `Genre`, `Poster`, etc.

How can I group each content with all the parameters? I am stuck here but from the group I know how to print into an Excel sheet.

Sample JSON response is below:

```
{
    facets: { },
    contents: [
       {
           id: "groupid://7110070",
           type: "group",
           adult: false,
           source: "group",
           instanceId: "groupid://7110070",
           parentalRating: {
           scheme: "custom",
           rating: 0
       },
```

I can't show the entire file due to security concerns.

Comment: You need to show your desired output. As it is, this question is very unclear.

Comment: @Chris.. Due to security concerns.. i didnt publish the whole file. There are 106 contents as per the JSON file. I need to group each content with all the parameters and should be able to print using a for loop for each content.

Comment: I presume that was a reply to me, not Chris. I'm not asking for the whole file, I just want an actual sample of what the output would look like.

Comment: @Daniel.. very sorry that i misunderstood between you and Chris. My desired output is as follows from the previous example file.

    Content1.id = 7110070
    Content1.type = group
    Content1.adult = false
    etc
    Content2.id = next value from json
like wise to all 106 contents

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand at all. How is that different from what you have already? `content[0].id == 7110070`, etc.

Comment: @Roshan, Add an example output to the question

Comment: Dan.the previous file there are 106 contents. Each content will be having Id, type, adult  etc. I need to group them just like an array or a dictionary. If i use a for loop inside each content, i should be able to get each parameter for each content. Each content will be having a poster URL also. So my main idea is to fetch the poster URL first, get that on a web page followed by all the other parameters. Then fetch the next poster and print the other parameters. Like wise, i need to do for all.

Comment: @amirouche.. Frankly speaking, i don't have an example output. Each content have a poster URL and many other parameters. So what i have to do is to group each content, fetch the poster from the URL and print on a web page followed by parameters for that content. Like wise, i need to do for all the remaining contents. I just asked the first part to get the grouping done and then i think i can carry out the printing on the web page stuff.

Comment: @Dan.. Actually those values are in the JSON. I am looking to extract those values from the JSON and keep them in an array or a dictionary.

Comment: But that can be done just with `result['contents']`.

Comment: Dan.. I didn't get you here.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group `contents` using a given key. Have look at [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) For more information.

In the following I group `contents` using the `category` key, which can be anything you want from the dictionary you have as input:

```
from itertools import groupby


contents = [
    dict(adult=True, id=111, name="Bob"),
    dict(adult=False, id=332, name="Chris"),
    dict(adult=True, id=113, name="John"),
    dict(adult=False, id=224, name="Amir"),
    dict(adult=True, id=115, name="Yann"),
    dict(adult=False, id=336, name="Lee"),
    dict(adult=False, id=227, name="Nadia"),
    dict(adult=False, id=228, name="Lucy")
]

# XXX: make sure to sort the content list
# with the key you want to group by
contents.sort(key=lambda content: content['adult'])

# then use groupby with the same key
groups = groupby(contents, lambda content: content['adult'])

for adult, group in groups:
    print 'adult', adult
    for content in group:
        print '\t', content
```

Here is the output:

```
adult False
    {'id': 332, 'name': 'Chris', 'adult': False}
    {'id': 224, 'name': 'Amir', 'adult': False}
    {'id': 336, 'name': 'Lee', 'adult': False}
    {'id': 227, 'name': 'Nadia', 'adult': False}
    {'id': 228, 'name': 'Lucy', 'adult': False}
adult True
    {'id': 111, 'name': 'Bob', 'adult': True}
    {'id': 113, 'name': 'John', 'adult': True}
    {'id': 115, 'name': 'Yann', 'adult': True}
```

Comment: amirouche.. I have a question here. Since the 'id' is from json file, how can i allocate the id values from there?     
From your example, i can allocate each category to be Name,  type etc but how can i allocate the id  ie values from the json?                                                                         


]

Comment: what do you mean by «allocate» ?

Comment: In the provided example, I only print the `id` but you have full access to the grouped dictionaries, so you can then use it to render the all the information found in the JSON contents dictionaries.

Comment: For eg: 1st content have Name as Bob, Id as 1, Adult as false. 2nd content have Name as Chris , Id as 2, Adult as True. Now with the example you provided, i can set the category to be Name, id and Adult but how will assign the values corresponding to each category to ID?

Comment: What you have given are the static id's, right? The data for me will be changed dynamically. So i should parse the json and assign the values. Then print it. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89273/discussion-between-amirouche-and-roshan-r).