# How do I group a list of row objects by year in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class for example:

```
class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, res_json):
        test = res_json['test']
        value = res_json['value']
        year = res_json['date'][0:4]
```

If I have a list of row objects and want to group them by year what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a json and grouping contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497253/parsing-a-json-and-grouping-contents)

Comment: Yes, I'm actually trying to avoid pandas due to schema issues with our system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

rows = []  # list of row objects

for year, group in groupby(rows, key=attrgetter('year')):
    # do stuff with the year and the group here
```