# Python - Extracting information from dictionary in a specific way

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to extract certain values from a dictionary and display it a specific way. I'll show you my code example below:

```
dict = [{'Titel': 'Rush', 'Name': 'Floris', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email': 'Floris@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Cake', 'Code': 'ABC123'},
 {'Titel': 'Rush', 'Voornaam': 'Jaron', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email': 'JaronPie@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Pie', 'Code': 'XYZ123'},
 {'Titel': 'Underneath', 'Name': 'Klaas', 'Starttime': '04:00', 'Email': 'Klassieboy@gmail.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Klassie', 'Code': 'fbhwuq8674'}]
```

That is my dictionary. What I want as output is:

```
Titel, Starttime,
Surname, Name, Email
```

So it would look like this:

```
Rush, 20:30, 
Cake, Floris, Floris@email.com
Pie, Jaron, JaronPie@email.com

Underneath, 04:00,
Klassie, Klaas, Klassieboy@gmail.com
```

Comment: do you know the dict keys before hand\

Comment: Yeah, they are all defined in a CSV file. They all follow the same format. Dict keys are: 'titel', 'name', 'starttime', 'email', 'supplier', 'surname', 'code'

Comment: do you also need group by titel

Comment: Yes, I need to group by Titel + Time.

Comment: It's not a dictionary it's a list of dictionaries, also the field should be 'Title' instead of 'Titel'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used VKS's code to build it thanks VKS :P

Using [groupy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby),[list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [sting formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

**Code:**

```
from itertools import groupby
k = [{'Titel': 'Rush', 'Name': 'Floris', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email':      'Floris@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Cake', 'Code': 'ABC123'},
{'Titel': 'Rush', 'Voornaam': 'Jaron', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email': 'JaronPie@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Pie', 'Code': 'XYZ123'},
{'Titel': 'Underneath', 'Name': 'Klaas', 'Starttime': '04:00', 'Email': 'Klassieboy@gmail.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Klassie', 'Code': 'fbhwuq8674'}]

lst=[(i["Titel"],i["Starttime"],i["Surname"],i.get("Name","None"), i["Email"]) for i in k]
lst.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))
for key,groups in groupby(lst,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1])):
    print "{}\t{}".format(key[0],key[1])
    for value in groups:
        print "{}\t{}\t{}".format(value[2],value[3],value[4])
    print ""
```

**Output:**

```
Rush    20:30
Cake    Floris  Floris@email.com
Pie     None    JaronPie@email.com

Underneath      04:00
Klassie Klaas   Klassieboy@gmail.com
```

Comment: That.. is... gorgeous! Exactly what I need! Thank you so much Vignesh.

Comment: @Cake happy to help but do look it to groupby and string formatting it will be usefull for you

Comment: you mean I should look into the module so that I can use it for future endeavors? If so, I certainly will!

Comment: @Cake yes I have also added links if you want to refer to

Answer (score 1):

```
k = [{'Titel': 'Rush', 'Name': 'Floris', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email':      'Floris@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Cake', 'Code': 'ABC123'},
 {'Titel': 'Rush', 'Voornaam': 'Jaron', 'Starttime': '20:30', 'Email': 'JaronPie@email.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Pie', 'Code': 'XYZ123'},
 {'Titel': 'Underneath', 'Name': 'Klaas', 'Starttime': '04:00', 'Email': 'Klassieboy@gmail.com', 'Supplier': 'RTL8', 'Surname': 'Klassie', 'Code': 'fbhwuq8674'}]

print [(i["Titel"],i["Starttime"],i["Surname"], i["Email"]) for i in k]
```

You can use this and you will get `tuple` of all info you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_my_d(d):

     print(d[0]['Titel'], d[0]['Starttime'])
     for l in d[:2]:
         print(l['Surname'], l['Name'], l['Email'])
     print()
     print(d[2]['Titel'],d[2]['Starttime'])
     print("{}, {}, {}".format(d[2]['Surname'],d[2]['Name'], d[2]['Email']))


print_my_d(d)

Rush 20:30
Cake Floris Floris@email.com
Pie Jaron JaronPie@email.com

Underneath 04:00
Klassie, Klaas, Klassieboy@gmail.com
```

Comment: Than you for replying @LetzerWille. You're very close, but it's not quite what I want. I want the Titel + Time to ONLY be printed once and all of the values that match that titel, within the dict, to be printed underneath.

Comment: @Cake. Changed to reflect what you need

Comment: @LetzerWille still some things are missing

Comment: @LetzerWille happy to help but this will not work if the sample cases changes that is instead of three element list the user can get one element list it is best to use group by

Comment: @VigneshKalai that's true. but even key naming can change. Nothing is eternal. I assume it is a toy for OP and not a production stuff. Meanwhile I will look closer at you general solution ...  I like it ...

Comment: @LetzerWille agreed :) and happy that you liked it :)