# How to get the groups generated by "groupby()" as lists?

Tags: python

I am testing `itertools.groupby()` and try to get the groups as lists but can't figure out how to make it work.

using the examples here, in [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"),
         ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]
```

I tried (python 3.5):

```
g = groupby(things, lambda x: x[0])
ll = list(g)
list(tuple(ll[0])[1])
```

I thought I should get the first group ("animal") as a list `['bear', 'duck']`. But I just get an empty list on REPL.

What am I doing wrong?

How should I extract all three groups as lists?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the groups, without the keys, you need to realize the group generators as you go, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list.

This means that when you try to `list`-ify the `groupby` generator first using `ll = list(g)`, before converting the individual group generators, all but the last group generator will be invalid/empty.

(Note that `list` is just one option; a `tuple` or any other container works too).

So to do it properly, you'd make sure to `list`ify each group generator before moving on to the next:

```
from operator import itemgetter  # Nicer than ad-hoc lambdas

# Make the key, group generator
gen = groupby(things, key=itemgetter(0))

# Strip the keys; you only care about the group generators
# In Python 2, you'd use future_builtins.map, because a non-generator map would break
groups = map(itemgetter(1), gen)

# Convert them to list one by one before the next group is pulled
groups = map(list, groups)

# And listify the result (to actually run out the generator and get all your
# results, assuming you need them as a list
groups = list(groups)
```

As a one-liner:

```
groups = list(map(list, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(things, key=itemgetter(0)))))
```

or because this many `map`s gets rather ugly/non-Pythonic, and list comprehensions let us do nifty stuff like unpacking to get named values, we can simplify to:

```
groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(things, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"),
         ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]


g = groupby(things, lambda x: x[0])
answer = [list(group[1]) for group in g]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'duck')],
 [('plant', 'cactus')],
 [('vehicle', 'speed boat'), ('vehicle', 'school bus')]]
```

Comment: The quote from @ShadowRanger's answer describes the problem: "Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible." By creating a list from the returned iterable, `ll = list(g)`, you advanced the iterator `g` all the way to its end, making all of the groups no longer available, causing them to seem empty.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Python Doc on [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) :

> `itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)` 
>   Make an iterator that returns
>   **consecutive keys and groups from the iterable**. The key is a function
>   computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None,
>   key defaults to an identity function and returns the element
>   unchanged. Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the
>   same key function.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"),
         ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for _, g in groupby(things, lambda x:x[0]):
    print(list(g))

[('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'duck')]
[('plant', 'cactus')]
[('vehicle', 'speed boat'), ('vehicle', 'school bus')]
>>>
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(things, itemgetter(0))]
>>> l
[[('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'duck')], [('plant', 'cactus')], [('vehicle', 'speed boat'), ('vehicle', 'school bus')]]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>>
>>> for k,v in groupby(things, itemgetter(0)):
    for sub in v:
        for item in sub:
            if item != k:
                d[k].append(item)


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'animal': ['bear', 'duck'], 'plant': ['cactus'], 'vehicle': ['speed boat', 'school bus']})
```