# How to remove duplicate values from defaultdict(int) in python?

Tags: python, duplicates, defaultdict

I have a dictionary which consists of unique key value pairs as follows:

```
    edu_bg={1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

I want to create a dictionary from above data so that similar records (which has similar values) are grouped together as follows:

```
   {(1, 3): 1, (5, 6): 1, (1, 4): 1, (2, 6): 1,(2, 5): 1, (3, 4): 1})
```

I tried to achieve above output using following code:

```
    myedu = defaultdict(int)
    for k,v in edu_bg.iteritems():
        for K,V in edu_bg.iteritems():
          if K == k and V == v:
              pass
          if K != k and V == v:
              myedu[(k,K)] += 1
          else:
              pass
```

However it has resulted in duplicate records as follows:

```
         defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(1, 3): 1, (5, 6): 1, (4, 1): 1, (3, 1): 1, (5, 2): 1, (1, 4): 1, (2, 6): 1, (4, 3): 1, (6, 2): 1, (2, 5): 1, (3, 4): 1, (6, 5): 1})
```

I want to remove these duplicate values. Any advice on this problem is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements. Why are (1,3) and (1,4) different? Why not (1,3,4)? This sounds like an XY problem...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/773/78845 . It may help you group your elements without writing lots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the cartesian product of every pair, which will iterated over exactly n^2 elements, you could just iterate over every possible combination, which will iterate over n(n-1)/2 elements. While the Big Oh complexity will be the same, the constant factors will be reduced significantly:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> myedu = defaultdict(int)
>>> edu_bg={1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
>>> for k1,k2 in combinations(edu_bg,2):
...   if edu_bg[k1] == edu_bg[k2]:
...     myedu[(k1,k2)] += 1
... 
>>> myedu
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(2, 6): 1, (1, 3): 1, (5, 6): 1, (2, 5): 1, (3, 4): 1, (1, 4): 1})
>>>
```

I should reiterate, though, this sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)...

Answer (score 2):

Inverting the mapping and taking the combinations of the groups of keys partitioned by their values.

```
>>> edu_bg={1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
>>> def invert(d):
...     i={}
...     for k,v in d.iteritems():
...             i.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
...     return i
... 
>>> invert(edu_bg)
{1: [1, 3, 4], 2: [2, 5, 6]}
```

Then for each of the sublists you compute `combinations(sublist, 2)`:

```
>>> [comb for sublist in {1: [1, 3, 4], 2: [2, 5, 6]}.values() for comb in combinations(sublist, 2)]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6)]
```

All the counts will always be 1 as each combination is generated only once.
Because of that we can generate the requested output simply:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([(1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6)], 1)
{(2, 6): 1, (5, 6): 1, (1, 4): 1, (1, 3): 1, (2, 5): 1, (3, 4): 1}
```

Each step combined

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([comb for sublist in invert(edu_bg).values() for comb in combinations(sublist, 2)],1)
{(2, 6): 1, (5, 6): 1, (1, 4): 1, (1, 3): 1, (2, 5): 1, (3, 4): 1}
```

This costs a lot less than either iterating over the product or the combinations and filtering. This also generates all the output without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing each key against all the other keys, including themselves. These leads to n**2 checks including two cases you don't want to consider: keys compared to themselves and keys compared twice. You've correctly passed on cases where the keys are equal.  You can pass on cases where a key `k` is smaller than the key `K` and this will dismiss the half of the checks that would have been duplicates.

```
from collections import defaultdict

edu_bg = {1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2}
myedu = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in edu_bg.iteritems():
    for K,V in edu_bg.iteritems():
        if K == k and V == v:
            pass
        if K > k and V == v:
            myedu[(k,K)] += 1
        else:
            pass
print myedu
```

Ideally you would limit the `for` loops such that the cases of keys being equally or twice counted would never happen. You can do that in the following way:

```
edu_bg = {1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2}
myedu = defaultdict(int)
keys = edu_bg.keys()
for i in xrange(len(keys)):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(keys)):
        k = keys[i]
        K = keys[j]
        if edu_bg[k] == edu_bg[K]:
            myedu[(k,K)] += 1         

print myedu
```