# What is itertools.groupby() used for?

Tags: python, python-itertools

While reading the python documentation I came across the `itertools.groupby()`
function. It was not very straightforward so I decided to look up some info here on stackoverflow. I found something from [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby).

There seems to be little info about it here and in the documentation so I decided I to post my observations for comments.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked [`grouby()` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)? Which part was not straight forward in this?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The first sentence of the OP's question states that they read the Python documentation.

Comment: you ask a question for which you have an elaborate answer prepared? really? why not have all that in the question and leave the answers section for discussion?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist [It's perfectly acceptable to ask a question for the sole purpose of answering it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I've done it myself.  "why not have all that in the question" Because an answer isn't part of a question. An answer is an answer.

Comment: @EmettSpeer My actual question is *"Which part was not straight forward in this?"*. I mentioned the link to the doc just to make sure that OP checked the official Python document, and not of any tutorial

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri That is very valid and I was not putting down your question. I was only pointing out that the first part of your question was already answered.

Comment: I would answer you Moinuddin. I am relatively new to Python and a lot of times I've often gotten frustrated looking for solutions. I read the docs. groupby() was the most complicated of all. I haven't really wrapped my head around the whole class thing. And the docs' examples were not so clear. I didn't think I'd sit around and wait for someone to ask the question before I answer. Hope my being proactive offends you not. And I stated clearly that I was only posting observations for comments. I might have missed a thing or added two.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To start with, you may read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

I will place what I consider to be the most important point first. I hope the reason will become clear after the examples.

**ALWAYS SORT ITEMS WITH THE SAME KEY TO BE USED FOR GROUPING SO AS TO AVOID UNEXPECTED RESULTS**

`itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None or some func)`
takes a list of iterables and groups them based on a specified key. The key specifies what action to apply to each individual iterable, the result of which is then used as the heading for each grouping the items; items which end up having same 'key' value will end up in the same group.

The return value is an iterable similar to a dictionary in that it is of the form `{key : value}`.

Example 1

```
# note here that the tuple counts as one item in this list. I did not
# specify any key, so each item in the list is a key on its own.
c = groupby(['goat', 'dog', 'cow', 1, 1, 2, 3, 11, 10, ('persons', 'man', 'woman')])
dic = {}
for k, v in c:
    dic[k] = list(v)
dic
```

results in

```
{1: [1, 1],
 'goat': ['goat'],
 3: [3],
 'cow': ['cow'],
 ('persons', 'man', 'woman'): [('persons', 'man', 'woman')],
 10: [10],
 11: [11],
 2: [2],
 'dog': ['dog']}
```

Example 2

```
# notice here that mulato and camel don't show up. only the last element with a certain key shows up, like replacing earlier result
# the last result for c actually wipes out two previous results.

list_things = ['goat', 'dog', 'donkey', 'mulato', 'cow', 'cat', ('persons', 'man', 'woman'), \
               'wombat', 'mongoose', 'malloo', 'camel']
c = groupby(list_things, key=lambda x: x[0])
dic = {}
for k, v in c:
    dic[k] = list(v)
dic
```

results in

```
{'c': ['camel'],
 'd': ['dog', 'donkey'],
 'g': ['goat'],
 'm': ['mongoose', 'malloo'],
 'persons': [('persons', 'man', 'woman')],
 'w': ['wombat']}
```

Now for the sorted version

```
 # but observe the sorted version where I have the data sorted first on same key I used for grouping
list_things = ['goat', 'dog', 'donkey', 'mulato', 'cow', 'cat', ('persons', 'man', 'woman'), \
               'wombat', 'mongoose', 'malloo', 'camel']
sorted_list = sorted(list_things, key = lambda x: x[0])
print(sorted_list)
print()
c = groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
dic = {}
for k, v in c:
    dic[k] = list(v)
dic
```

results in

```
['cow', 'cat', 'camel', 'dog', 'donkey', 'goat', 'mulato', 'mongoose', 'malloo', ('persons', 'man', 'woman'), 'wombat']
{'c': ['cow', 'cat', 'camel'],
 'd': ['dog', 'donkey'],
 'g': ['goat'],
 'm': ['mulato', 'mongoose', 'malloo'],
 'persons': [('persons', 'man', 'woman')],
 'w': ['wombat']}
```

Example 3

```
things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"), ("vehicle", "harley"), \
          ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]
dic = {}
f = lambda x: x[0]
for key, group in groupby(sorted(things, key=f), f):
    dic[key] = list(group)
dic
```

results in

```
{'animal': [('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'duck')],
 'plant': [('plant', 'cactus')],
 'vehicle': [('vehicle', 'harley'),
  ('vehicle', 'speed boat'),
  ('vehicle', 'school bus')]}
```

Now for the sorted version. I changed the tuples to lists here. Same results either way.

```
things = [["animal", "bear"], ["animal", "duck"], ["vehicle", "harley"], ["plant", "cactus"], \
          ["vehicle", "speed boat"], ["vehicle", "school bus"]]
dic = {}
f = lambda x: x[0]
for key, group in groupby(sorted(things, key=f), f):
    dic[key] = list(group)
dic
```

results in

```
{'animal': [['animal', 'bear'], ['animal', 'duck']],
 'plant': [['plant', 'cactus']],
 'vehicle': [['vehicle', 'harley'],
  ['vehicle', 'speed boat'],
  ['vehicle', 'school bus']]}
```

Comment: "`itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None or some func)` takes a list of iterables" Does it take a list of iterables, or just an iterable? A list is an iterable.

Comment: The docs doesn't say explicitly. But from the examples I posted you can see that I used both a list and nested list. So it can take an "iterable" (Example 1) as well as a "list of iterables" (Example 2). You may even pass in a single string and you'd still be in business

Answer (score 11):

As always the [documentation of the function](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) should be the first place to check. However `itertools.groupby` is certainly one of the trickiest `itertools` because it has some possible pitfalls:

- It only groups the items if their `key`-result is the same for successive items:

  ```
  from itertools import groupby

  for key, group in groupby([1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,4]):
      print(key, list(group))
  # 1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
  # 5 [5]
  # 1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
  # 4 [4]
  ```

  One could use `sorted` before - if one wants to do an overall `groupby`.
- It yields two items, and the second one is an iterator (so one needs to iterate over the second item!). I explicitly needed to cast these to a `list` in the previous example.
- The second yielded element is discarded if one advances the `groupby`-iterator:

  ```
  it = groupby([1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,4])
  key1, group1 = next(it)
  key2, group2 = next(it)
  print(key1, list(group1))
  # 1 []
  ```

  Even if `group1` isn't empty!

As already mentioned one can use `sorted` to do an overall `groupby` operation but that's extremely inefficient (and throws away the memory-efficiency if you want to use groupby on generators). There are better alternatives available if you can't guarantee that the input is `sorted` (which also don't require the `O(n log(n))` sorting time overhead):

- [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html#iteration_utilities.groupedby)
- probably more.

However it's great to check local properties. There are two recipes in the [`itertools`-recipes section](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    "Returns True if all the elements are equal to each other"
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

and:

```
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return map(next, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely take note in case I need some alternatives sometime. For now I'm reading the docs section by section so as not to jumble up everything. And a happy new  year to you

Comment: Great info here.  The documentation for `collections.defaultdict` has a very straightforward example about how to group values: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples