# variable call through combination string python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists dependent on each other like a person and where is he/she from.
I want to make groups based on where they are from.

```
People = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
City = ["Bombay","Delhi","Pune","Pune","Bombay","Pune"]
```

Here, A is from Bombay, B is from Delhi, and like that. I want to group all people from Bombay in one group, Delhi in one group, and Pune in one group.
Then I want to assign some task to each group, like people from Bombay will do task X, people from Delhi will do task Y, and people from Pune will do task Z.
How can I do that in python?

A group is like a list.
Example:

```
Bombay = ["A","E"]
Delhi = ["B"]
Pune = ["C","D","F"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? What is your expected result?

Comment: group is like list  example Bombay = ["A","E"] , Delhi = ["B"], Pune = ["C","D","F"]

Comment: @AakashPatel, If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

data = sorted(zip(People, City), key=lambda x: x[1])
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    g = [x[0] for x in g]
    print(f'{k} = {g}')
```

**Output:**

```
Bombay = ['A', 'E']
Delhi = ['B']
Pune = ['C', 'D', 'F']
```

Comment: i like your answer . can you please explain to me how this works ?

Comment: you need to know how the `itertools.groupby` works this will help [What is itertools.groupby() used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411492/what-is-itertools-groupby-used-for)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. But how to use new lists for further operation?

Comment: you can create dictionary. `res = {k: [x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[1])}`

Comment: Still not able to use . I try to take output as print(Bombay[0]) and its say Bombay is not defined

Comment: you should use `print(res['Bombay'][0])`

Comment: What if second list (city) is unknown and generated from input from the people of list People? How can I find out the elements from new list  ? I created one temp list and append the k in that list and then tried  print(res['temp[0]'][1])  but it is not working

Comment: In the example we have directly choose that A is from Bombay , B is from Delhi and so on.But if we have to take input from A that from which city he is and then to B and same to all people . This way city list is generate.  clear?

Comment: do you mean if we give `A` as input you want to get `Bombay` as output?

Comment: People = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
City = []

for i in People:
    a = input("Hello!! {} Where are you from? : ".format(i))
    City.append(a)
print(City)
# This is how city list will generate
# This list will used for further work

Comment: copy the code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link also add your issue in that file

Comment: as per your example just use `res[a][0]` will give the first element of Bombay list. there is no need of temp it's list of  keys in dictionary simply `temp = list(res.keys())`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution & storing in `dict` would be preferable over variable due to ease accessiblity.

```
result = {}

for c,p in zip(City, People):
    result.setdefault(c, []).append(p)

print(result)
```

---

```
{'Bombay': ['A', 'E'], 'Delhi': ['B'], 'Pune': ['C', 'D', 'F']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary

```
Dict = dict()

People = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
City = ["Bombay","Delhi","Pune","Pune","Bombay","Pune"]

for i in range (len (City)):
    if City[i] in Dict:
        Dict[City[i]].append (People[i])
    else:
        Dict[City[i]] = [ People[i] ]

for city in Dict:
    print (city, end = ': ')
    for people in Dict[city]:
        print (people, end = ' ')

    print()
```

This prints:

```
Bombay: A E 
Delhi: B 
Pune: C D F
```

Similarly, create another Dictionary for the tasks and assign a task as a value to every key (city) from the `city_of` Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
People = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
City = ["Bombay","Delhi","Pune","Pune","Bombay","Pune"]


data={}
for P in People:
    for C in City:
        data[P]=C

def X():
    print('do stuff X')
def Y():
    print('do stuff Y')
def Z():
    print('do stuff Z')
def A():
    print('do stuff A')

tasks={
    "Bombay":X(),
    "Delhi":Y(),
    "Pune":Z(),
    "Pune":A(),
    "Bombay":A(),
    "Pune":A()
}


for item in data:
    tasks[data[item]]
```

Comment: what if we have large number of cities? did you write `tasks` dictionary for all cities

Comment: I've posted my solution for a given problem, not the ultimate answer. You can reuse function when a couple of cities do the same task or write a new one for when it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you like one liners for maximum readability ;-) This list comprehension gets the unique cities and for every city name it gets the people in the zipped list that belong to this city:

```
people = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
cities = ["Bombay","Delhi","Pune","Pune","Bombay","Pune"]
    
result = [{city: [name[0]
 for name in list(zip(people, cities)) if name[1] == city]}
 for city in list(set(cities))]

print(result)
```

### Output

```
[{'Pune': ['C', 'D', 'F']}, {'Bombay': ['A', 'E']}, {'Delhi': ['B']}]
```