# Compare two lists A, B in Python find all elements in A which correspond to the same number in B

Tags: python, list

I want to compare two Python lists, 'A' and 'B' in such a manner that I can find **all elements in A** which correspond to the **same number in B**. I want to do this for **each number in B**. For example, if

```
A = [5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 16, 25]
B = [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

I would like to get

```
[7,16] corresponding to the number 1 of listB
[5, 12] corresponding to the number 2 of listB
[9, 8] corresponding to the number 3 of listB
[25] corresponding to the number 4 of listB
```

A and B will always have the same lengths.

Comment: Not sure to understand the logic here... Could you please give more details? `[7,16] corresponding to the number 1 of listB` ... Why ?

Comment: Ohhh ok I get it : in list B, there are `1` at the 2nd and 6th position and the numbers in list A at these positions are 7 and 16.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create tuples which consist from one element from both lists, then sort them and finally group them by value from `B`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> A = [5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 16, 25]
>>> B = [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4]
>>> for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(B,A)), key=lambda x: x[0]):
...     print('{} corresponds to {}'.format([x[1] for x in g], k))
... 
[7, 16] corresponds to 1
[5, 12] corresponds to 2
[8, 9] corresponds to 3
[25] corresponds to 4
```

In above `zip(B, A)` returns iterable of tuples where each tuple has element from `B` and `A`:

```
>>> list(zip(B,A))
[(2, 5), (1, 7), (3, 9), (2, 12), (3, 8), (1, 16), (4, 25)]
```

Result of above is then sorted so that all the tuples with same value from `B` are next to each other:

```
>>> sorted(zip(B,A))
[(1, 7), (1, 16), (2, 5), (2, 12), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 25)]
```

Result of sorting is passed to [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which groups the tuples based on value returned by key function, in this case the first item in the tuple. Result is iterable of `(key, group)` tuples where group is iterable of elements:

```
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(B,A)), key=lambda x: x[0])]
[(1, [(1, 7), (1, 16)]), (2, [(2, 5), (2, 12)]), (3, [(3, 8), (3, 9)]), (4, [(4, 25)])]
```

Comment: very elegant response

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach.

```
unique = set(B)    # Creates a set of unique entries in B
for u in unique:
    # Find indices of unique entry u
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(B) if x == u]

    # Pull out these indices in A
    corrEntry = [A[i] for i in indices]  

    # Do something with the data, in this case print what OP wants
    print('{} corresponds to the number {} of list B'.format(corrEntry , B[indices[0]]))
```

It finds the unique entries in B by using the `set` function. 
We then loop through these unique entries. The first list comprehension (for `indices`) finds the indices of the entries in B that match this unique entry. The second saves the value in A of those indices.

Comment: your code is actually not working. I have run it, and it is not what the user is asking for. `print(indices, correspondingEntries)`, and I am getting `[1, 5] [7, 16]
[0, 3] [5, 12]
[2, 4] [9, 8]
[6] [25]`

Comment: Just print `correspondingEntries`. `indices` isn't need for anything and is an intermediary

Comment: the point is that @SiddTheKid will want the number at which this entries are the same that is the main point of the question

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this code:

```
A = [5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 16, 25]
B = [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4]

d = {}

for a, b in zip(A, B):
    d.setdefault(b, [])
    d[b].append(a)

for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print('{} corresponds {}'.format(v, k))
```

Each key of the dictionary will be an element of `B`, and its associated value will be the list you want.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections as ct

dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    dd[b].append(a)

dd
# defaultdict(list, {1: [7, 16], 2: [5, 12], 3: [9, 8], 4: [25]})
```

Sample of printed results:

```
for k, v in sorted(dd.items()):
    print("{} corresponding to the number {} of listB".format(v, k))

# [7, 16] corresponding to the number 1 of listB
# [5, 12] corresponding to the number 2 of listB
# [9, 8] corresponding to the number 3 of listB
# [25] corresponding to the number 4 of listB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [5, 7, 9, 12, 8, 16, 25]
B = [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Create a specific function that takes two lists (`A`, `B`) and a number (`n`) as arguments.  Select all items in `A` that have the same list position as the items in `B` that are equivalent to `n`.  [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is used to pair items from `A` and `B` with the same list position.  This function uses a list comprehension to select the items from `A`.

```
>>> def f(A, B, n):
    return [a for a, b in zip(A,B) if b == n]

>>> f(A, B, 2)
[5, 12]
>>>
```

The function could be written without a list comprehension:

```
def g(A, B, n):
    result = []
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        if b == n:
            result.append(a)
    return result
```

Using fuctools.partial the list arguments can be fixed:

```
import functools
f_AB = functools.partial(f, A, B)
```

Then it could be used like this:

```
>>> f_AB(3)
[9, 8]

>>> numbers = [3, 4, 2]
>>> for n in numbers:
    print (n, f_AB(n))

(3, [9, 8])
(4, [25])
(2, [5, 12])
>>>
```

Comment: Some explanation might help.

Comment: thnx, @Pavlo - I got a bit lazy.