# Sorting and filtering a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have list like this:

```
[['Richard', 1, 'Group A'], ['Mark', 3, 'Group A'],
 ['Alan', 4, 'Group B'], ['Dave', 3, 'Group B'],
 ['Gordon', 2, 'Group A']]
```

That I would like to filter so that only the lowest number (Richard has a number of 1, Mark is 3, Alan is 4, etc.) of each group is kept so that the list would look like:

```
[['Richard', 1, 'Group A'], ['Dave', 3, 'Group B']]
```

I'm sorting with the lambda key:

```
filteredList = sorted(list,key=lambda x: x[2])
```

But I'm blocked when it comes to sorting within each group and getting rid of higher ranking individuals.

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Python or should I iterate and test each row?

Comment: You prob got a down vote cos you're supposed to try first and post your attempt.

Comment: Should `'Grpup A'` be `Group A`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)

Comment: @TemporalWolf -- you're assuming here that `groupby` is the best solution here.  Algorithmically, it doesn't have the optimal Big-O (it's at least O(NlogN)) whereas an O(N) solution can be created using a dict...

Comment: @Rodolphe -- Does the order of the output list actually matter?  would `list = [['Dave', 3, 'Group B'], ['Richard', 1, 'Group A']]` be acceptable?

Comment: @mgilson he specifically asks for *sorting and filtering*. You may disagree with his premise, but that's what the OP asked for... and for a general solution you probably can't beat itertools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-key the data off of the group name.  Don't name your data `list` because it shadows a built-in name.

```
>>> results = {}
>>> for name, number, group in data:
...     key = group
...     value = number, name
...     results[key] = min(value, results.get(key, value))
...     
>>> [[name, number, group] for group, (number, name) in results.items()]
[['Dave', 3, 'Group B'], ['Richard', 1, 'Group A']]
```

Pure python data structures handle this problem quite nicely, the sort/itertools approach is suboptimal and increases complexity from O(n) to O(n logn).

Comment: To meet spec this does require a sort at the end, but a result sort will be far less expensive than sorting the entire input: `O(n + m log m)` where `m` is the # of groups, so `m < n`

Comment: Using timeit, this solution is faster than both other options on the same data according: if it must be sorted it's only slightly faster: if unsorted it takes about 60% the time of a defaultdict implementation. And that savings will explode as `m << n` if you do need it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` in order to group your sub lists based on 3rd item then use `min()` function with a proper key within a list comprehension in order to get the expected result:

```
In [61]: from operator import itemgetter
In [62]: from collections import defaultdict
In [63]: lst = [['Richard', 1, 'Group A'], ['Mark', 3, 'Group A'], ['Alan', 4, 'Group B'], ['Dave', 3, 'Group B'], ['Gordon', 2, 'Group A']]

In [64]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [65]: for i, j, k in lst:
             d[k].append([i, j, k])
   ....:     

In [66]: [min(sub, key=itemgetter(1)) for sub in d.values()]
Out[66]: [['Dave', 3, 'Group B'], ['Richard', 1, 'Group A']]
```

You can do this even in a more optimized manner by passing a customized object to `defaultdict()`, so that it only appends new items if they have a smaller second item:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class MyList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def special_append(self, arg):
        if not self:
            self.append(arg)
        elif arg[1] < self[0][1]:
            self[0] = arg
```

Demo:

```
lst = [['Richard', 1, 'Group A'], ['Mark', 3, 'Group A'], ['Alan', 4, 'Group B'], ['Dave', 3, 'Group B'], ['Gordon', 2, 'Group A']]

d = defaultdict(MyList)

for i, j, k in lst:
    d[k].special_append([i, j, k])

print(d)

defaultdict(<class '__main__.MyList'>, {'Group B': [['Dave', 3, 'Group B']], 'Group A': [['Richard', 1, 'Group A']]})
```

Comment: Am I the only one who wonders what 60 commands you typed before these 7?  :-)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein They're not because of this, I always type command in Ipython even for a simple calculation :-D.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple "bin and find min" problem.  The first pass, we'll bin:

```
from collections import defaultdict
bins = defaultdict(list)
for item in input_list:
    bins[item[2]].append(item)
```

Now we just need to take the minimum of each of the bins:

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_second = itemgetter(1)
results = [min(group, key=get_second) for group in bins.values()]
```

Up to this point, we have an O(N) algorithm (binning happens in O(1) time for each of the `N` items we put in the dict) and finding the `min` runs over each of the items exactly once more -- so that's O(N) too...

---

If necessary, you can then sort the results by group name:

```
results.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
```

---

We can do the `min` step and binning step at the same time to save a bit of memory (e.g. if the input is coming from a generator and has *lots* of items):

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_second = itemgetter(1)
results = {}
for item in input_stream:
    group = item[2]
    if group not in results:
        results[group] = item
    else:
        results[group] = min(item, results[group], key=get_second)
```

This is effectively a different implementation of the same idea as the solution provided by [@wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146410/748858). To order the results when you're done (if necessary):

```
 ordered_results = sorted(results.values(), key=itmegetter(2))
```

In this way, we only keep one result for each group around.  The cost is a bit of extra code complexity.

Comment: This approach requires duplicating the entire list into a defaultdict, which, while asymptotically more efficient than itertools, is still likely not the best `O(n)` approach for this problem. Building a solution set only, rather than an entire dict, should be much faster and requires significantly less space for the intermediate storage.

Comment: This is exactly the same as [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42146280/674039) solution, whoever wasn't first should delete ...

Comment: @TemporalWolf -- Sure.  I find that separating things into different stages is easier to think about from a logical standpoint.  I disagree with your assertion that it requires "significantly" less space.  I'm only storing more references to existing lists -- IOW, it's roughly an additional `N` pointers which is going to be significantly smaller than the original.  Of course, if OP wanted to use a generator as an input then maybe it'd be a different story ;-)

Comment: @wim -- I think that the other solution beat mine by about 10s, however, mine also discusses how to think about the algorithmic complexity and how to sort the final results to get exactly what OP originally asked for.  IOW, I agree that mine isn't much different than the other solution but it does have things that the other answer doesn't have.  If Kasramvd wants to edit those things into his/her answer and let me know that they're there, then I'm happy to delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it something like `key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1])`. Then you have two-level sorting.

Alternatively, `operator.itemgetter` can take multiple indices.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TemporalWolf in the comments that `itertools.groupby` is the right approach to take.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

in_ = [['Richard', 1, 'Group A'], ['Mark', 3, 'Group A'],
       ['Alan', 4, 'Group B'], ['Dave', 3, 'Group B'],
       ['Gordon', 2, 'Group A']]

groups = groupby(in_, key=itemgetter(2))
# operator.itemgetter(N) is equivalent to lambda x: x[N]
```

The groupby function creates something akin to:

```
[("Group A", [['Richard', 1, 'Group A'],
              ['Mark', 3, 'Group A'],
              ['Gordon', 2, 'Group A']]),
 ("Group B", [['Alan', 4, 'Group B'],
              ['Dave', 3, 'Group B']])]
```

Then it's easy enough to iterate and use `min` to find the results

```
minimums = []
for _, vals in groups:
    minimums.append(min(vals, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Comment: You can be even more clever here.  If you sort on `itemgetter(2, 1)`, then you don't even need to use `min` on the groups -- You just take the first item in each group and you're done.  Ultimately though, I'm not sure if that's better than what you have here (I'd have to think about it a bit more)