# How to create subset lists with underscores from a list Python

Tags: python, list, subset, list-comprehension

I have a list called animals,

```
animals = ["B_FOX", "A_CAT", "A_DOG", "A_MOUSE", 
         "B_DOG", "B_MOUSE", "C_DUCK", "C_FOX", "C_BIRD"]
```

and would like the following outputs:

```
 A = ["A_CAT", "A_DOG", "A_MOUSE"]
 B = ["B_DOG", "B_MOUSE", "B_FOX"]
 C = ["C_DUCK", "C_FOX", "C_BIRD"]
```

I can only get a subset list of only the letters or the animals like this:

```
  [species.split("_",1)[1] for species in animals]
  ['FOX', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'MOUSE', 'DOG', 'MOUSE', 'DUCK', 'FOX', 'BIRD']

  [letters.split("_",1)[0] for letters in animals]
  ['B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Not sure if I've worded the question correctly. Any help in solving this tricky problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: explain how you would imagine proceeding from here in words and you'll find help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the values of the prefix and the name both from one call to `split`:

```
groups = {}
for animal in animals:
    prefix, name = animal.split("_")
    if prefix not in groups:
        groups[prefix] = []
    groups[prefix].append(animal)

print groups
```

> {'A': ['A_CAT', 'A_DOG', 'A_MOUSE'], 'C': ['C_DUCK', 'C_FOX', 'C_BIRD'], 'B': ['B_FOX', 'B_DOG', 'B_MOUSE']}

If required, you can later still unpack the dict into single variables:

```
A = groups["A"]
B = groups["B"]
C = groups["C"]
```

If you want to get rid of the prefixes:

```
groups = {}
for animal in animals:
    prefix, name = animal.split("_")
    if prefix not in groups:
        groups[prefix] = []
    groups[prefix].append(name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could build separate lists, one for each initial letter, however, that would be tricky if you have many letters. You can use a `defaultdict` instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
animals = ["B_FOX", "A_CAT", "A_DOG", "A_MOUSE", 
     "B_DOG", "B_MOUSE", "C_DUCK", "C_FOX", "C_BIRD"]

for animal in animals:
   d[animal[0]].append(animal)
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['A_CAT', 'A_DOG', 'A_MOUSE'], 'C': ['C_DUCK', 'C_FOX', 'C_BIRD'], 'B': ['B_FOX', 'B_DOG', 'B_MOUSE']}
```

Comment: Hey Ajax, thanks for the help! The output is cool, seems to work.

Comment: @MichaelRSF glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Try an `itertools.groupby` according to the first letter:

```
import operator as op
import itertools as it


animals = [
    "B_FOX", "A_CAT", "A_DOG", "A_MOUSE", 
    "B_DOG", "B_MOUSE", "C_DUCK", "C_FOX", "C_BIRD"
]

A, B, C = [list(g) for _, g in it.groupby(sorted(animals), key=op.itemgetter(0))]
```

Outputs:

```
A
# ['A_CAT', 'A_DOG', 'A_MOUSE']

B
# ['B_DOG', 'B_FOX', 'B_MOUSE']

C
# ['C_BIRD', 'C_DUCK', 'C_FOX']
```

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873519/4531270) on how `groupby` works.

Comment: That's very neat, I wasn't aware of the operator module til now. Thanks pylang!

Comment: The other key option is a regular function, such as `def f(x): x[0]` or `lambda x: x[0]`

Comment: This would be last on readability and ease of understanding but it definitely wins for the shortest solution ;-)

Comment: @Hubert Grzeskowiak, I might agree on understanding, which is how `groupby` is.  It is one of the tougher and trickier itertools to grok.  But, I think it reads fine.  I'll add a link for clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution as well, Hubert! Much appreciated for all the help :)