# pythonic way to find all potential longest sequence

Tags: python

So, I have a list like following

```
potential_labels = ['foo', 'foo::bar', 'foo::bar::baz', "abc", "abc::cde::def", "bleh"]
```

The `desired_output = ['foo::bar::baz', "abc::cde::def", "bleh"]`

This is because.. for root "foo", 'foo::bar::baz' is the longest sequence
for "abc", "abc::cde::def", and for "bleh" it "bleh"

Is there any python inbuilt function which does this.. I feel like there is almost something in itertools which does this but cant seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`max` + `groupby` should do it.

```
r = [max(g, key=len) for _, g in \
          itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x.split('::')[0])]

r
['foo::bar::baz', 'abc::cde::def', 'bleh']
```

---

**Option 2**
A much simpler solution would involve the `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict()    
for x in data:
    o.setdefault(x.split('::')[0], []).append(x)

r = [sorted(o[k], key=len)[-1] for k in o]

r
['foo::bar::baz', 'abc::cde::def', 'bleh']
```

Not exactly a one liner, but *what is pythonic* is subjective after all.

Comment: It is only inefficient by a log(n) factor; you need to traverse the list anyway, probably twice to (1) get the maxlen, and (2) to extract the values.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks, that was informative. I can think of doing this with a loop and dict, that would probably speed things up a bit.

Comment: The OP sort of asked for a pythonic way, & your answer delivers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think you can use `max` instead of `sorted`, e.g. `[max(list(g), key=len) for ...]`

Comment: @pylang Yes, absolutely. Wonder why I didn’t see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple list comprehension taking advantage of a condition:

```
>>> [label for label in potential_labels if "\0".join(potential_labels).count("\0{}".format(label))==1]
['foo::bar::baz', 'abc::cde::def', 'bleh']
```

Comment: This doesnt work if `potential_labels=[u'Reggae', u'Reggae::Dancehall', u'Reggae::Reggae-Pop', u'Reggae::Contemporary Reggae', u'Reggae::Ragga', u'Reggae', u'Reggae::Dancehall', u'Reggae::Reggae-Pop', u'Reggae::Contemporary Reggae', u'Reggae::Ragga']`